# Gerrit recreating change-ids

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using gerrit. I used the following command

```
$ cd .git/hooks
$ scp -P 29418 demo@localhost:hooks/commit-msg .
$ cd ../..
```

This adds the change-id to my commit message, however if I amend to a commit it creates a NEW change-id. So when I push back to gerrit it's not adding the patch set, it's creating a whole new review entry.

Any suggests please?

Found the answer, but stackoverflow won't let me answer my own question.

So this was a complete error on my part.
When I was trying to commit
    git commit --amend -m "Initial Commit"

I was inlining the commit message and that was wiping away the change-Id, thus giving me a new one.

Comment: Are you sure that the ChangeId is in the last paragraph of the commit message? Have a look at: [ChangeId](http://gerrit.chromium.org/gerrit/Documentation/user-changeid.html)

Comment: Mmmm, I have just finished reading your question :-) and yes, the -m is a typical error.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

commit-msg hook work that way:

1. Check if you have change-id in your commit message.
2. If not, generates one.

If you type `git commit --amend` and edit commit message, you still have old change-id (it is good).

But if you type `git commit --amend -m "...."` you have removed change-id, so gerrit generates new one.

Rule of a thumb:
Don't use `--amend -m` with gerrit.

Comment: If you really wanted to, one could write a prepare-commit-msg hook that would squirrel away the changeid and then put it back on.

Comment: Yikes! found this too late :)

Comment: --ammend and -m do work ... you just have to remember to to a `git rebase --interactive` before pushing - to cleanup things. And of course, you have to make sure to not change the change id when doing so ;-)

Answer (score 7):

1. `git commit --amend`
2. Manually delete the *Change-Id* line, save and close
3. `git commit --amend --no-edit`

And the hook will create a new Change-Id hash, in the absence of one.

Comment: That is in fact the easiest way to re-generate change-id, and shall be accepted as a correct way

Answer (score 1):

If `git commit --amend` or `git commit --amend -m "...."` doesn't help and gerrit still complains about the missing change-Id. (This happens due to network issues mostly)

This is how I got it resolved (Made sure I had the commit-msg hook applied, on parent directory of the checked-out directory [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854122/git-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory-protocol-error-expected-control-record)):

1. Stash the Changes using `git stash`.
2. Used `gitk &` to hard rebase the change to just previous commit.
   [image]
3. Then pull and rebase from Repo `git pull --rebase`.
4. Then apply the stashed changes using `git stash apply`, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003009/git-how-to-recover-stashed-uncommitted-changes/19003191#19003191).
   Resolve Merger Conflicts if any using `git mergetool`.
5. Recommitted in the change again using `git commit` or `git commit --amend`, this generated a new change-Id
6. Push the changes to branch on repository using `git push ...` command.

There is similar question around as well [for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845658/gerrit-error-when-change-id-in-commit-messages-are-missing)