# Update remote repo from local repo after crash?

Tags: git, gerrit

My remote server crashed, fortunately I had a backup, but this backup is one week old. Since then I have committed and merged several changes.

How do I re-commit all my changes from the local repo, or update the remote repo from the local repo?

When I try to push a new commit, I get this error:

! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (missing Change-Id in commit message footer)

Comment: It looks like you have something else besides Git running on your server, maybe Gerrit? Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845658/gerrit-error-when-change-id-in-commit-messages-are-missing for a solution

Comment: This is Gerrit-related isssue. Otherwise, pushing to the remote is the right thing to do.

Comment: Yes, it is true. I use Gerrit for reviewing the commits. Looking at the answer Nils posted now.