# ChangeId is not generated in Eclipse for Gerrit commit

Tags: eclipse, git, gerrit

I want to commit my changes in Eclipse (using Git and Gerrit), but I can't generate any changeId that is necessary for the commit process. I haven't found any link during my online search. I checked the keys, I integrated in Eclipse, I can access to the Gerrit Git server without any problem.

Any Idea?

Best

Comment: Did you install the [commit-msg hook](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11/user-changeid.html#creation) in your Git repository? It should generate the `Change-Id:`-lines automatically.

Comment: It works now. I was irritated by the changeID I00000...so we could close this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Great! If you found a solution yourself, it is completely acceptable for you to write and accept an answer for your own question.

Comment: @helmbert wondering how did you solve this problem?

Comment: This might be a bug in egit, for me also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

For the Eclipse EGerrit plugin to work one must:

1. Install the git commit hook as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845658/gerrit-error-when-change-id-in-commit-messages-are-missing)
2. Click on "Add Change-id" button in Eclipse as pictured

[EGerrit "Add Change-id" button location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSHun.png)

This will generate an empty change id full of zeroes, which will be replaced automatically with the actual change id after you commit.

3. If you want gerrit to insert it automatically make sure the file `[your_project]/.git/config` contains

> [gerrit]
>       createchangeid = true

(The `createchangeid = true` line should be indented with a tab

4. If you forgot to add the change id and already committed you can amend your last commit (by clicking the corresponding button: second to the left from the change id button) and then hit the change id button. To add change ids to several commits see the first SO link.