# egit error : missing subject; Change-Id must be in commit message footer

Tags: git, gerrit

I use egit to commit my files in eclipse to the gerrit server. I've added the change-Id using egit "Add change Id" button in the git staging view. Nevertheless I still have the error message "missing subject; Change-Id must be in commit message footer" while pushing!

Here is what my commit message looks like in egit using the Amend last commit message button :

> CVS et load de config
>
> Signed-off-by: xxx
>
> Change-Id: Idda4d4ab44d0fa825755415f91b2b706b403b0e8

I try to push using git bash and get the same error message even after the command

> scp -p -P 29418 dxxx@myhost.fr:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/

Comment: So that we are all clear, you experienced this error when trying to _amend_ a commit?

Comment: Have a look at the `git log`. There seem commits that still lack the `Change-Id:` line.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : no it's while pushing the files commited.

Comment: @StephenKing : indeed I've done a revert on several of them but I still have the same error. Is there a way to know which commit is wrong? I'm working on windows, the tools I used aren't easy : egit and Git Bash.

Comment: Is revert the right action to do on the wrong commit?

Comment: No, you have to rewrite history. Reverts don't remove the old commits, but you try to push them. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845658/gerrit-error-when-change-id-in-commit-messages-are-missing).

Comment: When you amend a commit, you rewrite it.  Perhaps the commit message somehow ended up in a state which could cause this problem.