# Why am I getting "Error failed to push some refs"?

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using Git with Gerrit and trying to push the changes with the following command

```
 git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

which is failing with following error message

> Counting objects: 54, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done. Writing objects: 100%
>   (54/54), 4.56 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 54 (delta 20), reused 0
>   (delta 0) remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (20/20) remote: Processing
>   changes: refs: 1, done remote: ERROR: [041a9f9] missing Change-Id in
>   commit message footer remote: remote: Hint: To automatically insert
>   Change-Id, install the hook: remote:   gitdir=$(git rev-parse
>   --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 urid@gerrit.ext.net.something.com:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
>   remote: And then amend the commit: remote:   git commit --amend
>   remote: To ssh://gerrit.ext.net.something.com:29418/Project/FolderName
>   ! [remote rejected]   HEAD -> refs/for/master ([041a9f9] missing
>   Change-Id in commit message footer) error: failed to push some refs to
>   'ssh://username@gerrit.ext.net.something.com:29418/Project/FolderName'

So as mentioned in above error message i run below command

```
--git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 urid@gerrit.ext.net.something.com:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
```

and output was

> commit-msg
>   100% 4682    23.0KB/s   00:00

So it mean hook downloaded properly in my project working directory after that i run the command

```
git commit --amend
```

and it is showing proper `Change-Id: I55862204ef71f69bc88c79fe2259f7cb8365699a` and as mentioned in this [documents](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-missing-changeid.html) its in the last line only.

But still i am not able to push the changes i tried to get help from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845658/gerrit-error-when-change-id-in-commit-messages-are-missing/20370265) but still its failing with same message.

**Update 1**
Here is the output of

```
$ git log
```

> commit 10690fb1b829981852855aecaab0dfd7aaf9997f (HEAD -> master)
>   Author:  Author Name
>
> Date:   Wed Jun 6 18:42:25 2018 +0530
>
> ```
> SUREREQ-6877:Support of PATCH and OPTIONS
>
> Change-Id: Ic7f36b90832078afa740b1138cb35829456f389d
> ```
>
> commit 041a9f9deeae886c9771995a1463d40ca2d3fa3c Merge: e265b88b
>   7f2ec936 Author:  Author Name   Date:   Wed Jun 6 17:33:48 2018 +0530
>
> ```
> Merge branch 'master' of ssh://gerrit.ext.net.nokia.com:29418/SURE/sure-sw
> ```
>
> commit e265b88b6194f65dedbf070b2be7f6c7018f6dec Author:  Author Name
>   Date:   Wed Jun 6 16:59:58 2018 +0530
>
> ```
> SUREREQ-6877:Support of PATCH and OPTIONS
>
> Change-Id: I82382926d5acd8f9101bd3fc7bbb33bae85672da
> ```
>
> commit 7603b20691b59de2f086ca5633314f89bcc963ab Author:  Author Name
>   Date:   Wed Jun 6 16:53:04 2018 +0530
>
> ```
> SUREREQ-6877:Support of PATCH and OPTIONS
>
> Change-Id: I9312ebbe3d346ff97ca996c2219f204a55d1b9ac
> ```
>
> commit 305fd46084f2a230f96b316f814ebf0eabd849c2 Author:  Author Name
>   Date:   Wed Jun 6 16:52:24 2018 +0530
>
> ```
> SUREREQ-6877:Support of PATCH and OPTIONS
>
> Change-Id: I011e3e3c22954774e99462c585a54cf9a0aad428
> ```
>
> commit 8b1059922745a605851f4a9bd6cae3193a85c62c Author: Author Name
>   Date:   Wed Jun 6 16:49:15 2018 +0530
>
> ```
> SUREREQ-6877:Support of PATCH and OPTIONS
>
> Change-Id: Ic9d9e7e787f8a826f18f361cf0c20930c42bf04b
> ```
>
> commit 7f2ec936f4133988194b14dca910fb921a6946be (origin/master,
>   origin/HEAD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue is not in the last commit. Probably the issue (the missing Change-Id) is on a parent commit. Execute the `git log` command and inspect your commit history looking for any new commit without the Change-Id. Remember: all new commits must have a unique Change-Id. If this is the case, you need to use the `git rebase -i` command to add the Change-Id to the commits.

Comment: I did not added it but I checked it's showing proper id and user name.

Answer (score 0):

You commit `041a9f9deeae886c9771995a1463d40ca2d3fa3c` is a merge commit and it does not have a Change-ID. This was probably created locally and Git does not run the commit-msg hook on merge commits. You need to make sure that you fix this before you can submit your change.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git pull origin -r master` to flatten the merge commit in which `Change-Id` is missing. The merge commit is redundant.