# cannot insert change-id line in .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG

Tags: git

I am getting the following error when i am trying to do git commit

```
panther2@ubuntu:~/panther1/.repo/manifests$ git commit -m "Adding manifest for release"
git: 'interpret-trailers' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
cannot insert change-id line in .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

This is the first time, i am getting the error. There were previous commits

Comment: Your git version may be too old to support this command.

Comment: Why was this error not occurred in the previous commits?

Comment: My git version is  1.9.1

Comment: The command is called in the hook `commit-msg`. Has `commit-msg` been updated?

Comment: We don't use commit-msg hook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My git version is 1.9.1

Try first and [update Git on your Ubuntu to its latest version](http://lifeonubuntu.com/upgrading-ubuntu-to-use-the-latest-git-version/), to see if the error message persists.

Check also the content of your commit message (since you had previous commits which completed successfully)

[Having `Change-Id` in the message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8849682/6309) would indeed trigger that command.

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked like a charm.