# git stash and apply

Tags: git, git-pull, git-stash

I'm new to git and not quite clear on how stashing works.

Let's say I'm working on branch master and try to `git pull` and receive the error that my local changes would be overwritten and need to be stashed or committed. If I haven't staged any of my changes and run `git stash`, then do a `git pull` and and update successfully, what happens when I `git stash apply`?

In general, If someone else modifies files and I run `git pull`, what happens when I `run git stash apply`? does it overwrite the files that were just updated, regardless of whether or not they were staged when I stashed them? Does it overwrite every file that I just updated with `git pull`, with the files that were stashed?

Comment: From the Git Book: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing

Answer (score 94, accepted):

#### Quick "TL;DR" take-away version, so one can come back later and study more

`git stash` hangs a stash-bag—this is a peculiar form of a merge commit that is not on any branch—on the current `HEAD` commit.  A later `git stash apply`, when you're at any commit—probably a *different* commit—then tries to restore the *changes* git computes by looking at both the hanging stash-bag and the commit it hangs from.

When you're done with the changes, you should use `git stash drop` to let go of the stash-bag from the commit it was "stashed on".  (And, `git stash pop` is just shorthand for "apply, then automatically drop".  I recommend keeping the two steps separate, though, in case you don't like the result of "apply" and you want to try again later.)

#### The long version

`git stash` is actually fairly complex.

It's been said that ["git makes much more sense once you understand X"](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/git-makes-more-sense-when-you-understand-x.html), for many different values of "X", which generalizes to "git makes much more sense once you understand git". :-)

In this case, to *really* understand `stash`, you need to understand how commits, branches, the index/staging-area, git's reference name space, and merges all work, because `git stash` creates a very peculiar merge commit that is referred-to by a name outside the usual name-spaces—a weird kind of merge that is not "on a branch" at all—and `git stash apply` uses git's merge machinery to attempt to "re-apply" the changes saved when the peculiar merge commit was made, optionally preserving the distinction between staged and unstaged changes.

**Fortunately**, you don't actually need to understand all of that to *use* `git stash`.

Here, you're working on some branch (`master`) and you have some changes that aren't ready yet, so you don't want to commit them on the branch.<sup>1</sup>  Meanwhile someone else put something good—or at least, you hope it's good—into the `origin/master` over on the remote repo, so you want to pick those up.

Let's say that you and they both started with commits that end in `- A - B - C`, i.e., `C` is the final commit that you had in your repo when you started working on branch `master`.  The new "something good" commits, we'll call `D` and `E`.

In your case you're running `git pull` and it fails with the "working directory not clean" problem.  So, you run `git stash`.  This commits your stuff for you, in its special weird stash-y fashion, so that your working directory is now clean.  Now you can `git pull`.

In terms of drawing of commits (a graph like you get with `gitk` or `git log --graph`), you now have something like this.  The stash is the little bag-of-`i-w` dangling off the commit you were "on", in your `master` branch, when you ran `git stash`.  (The reason for the names `i` and `w` is that these are the "i"ndex / staging-area and "w"ork-tree parts of the stash.)

```
- A - B - C - D - E      <-- HEAD=master, origin/master
          |\
          i-w            <-- the "stash"
```

This drawing is what you get if you started working on `master` and never did *any* commits.  The most recent commit you had was thus `C`.  After making the stash, `git pull` was able to add commits `D` and `E` to your local branch `master`.  The stashed bag of work is still hanging off `C`.

If you made a few commits of your own—we'll call them `Y`, for your commit, and `Z` just to have two commits—the result of the "stash then pull" looks like this:

```
                   .-------- origin/master
- A - B - C - D - E - M  <-- HEAD=master
            \       /
              Y - Z
                  |\
                  i-w    <-- the "stash"
```

This time, after `stash` hung its stash-bag off `Z`, the `pull`—which is just `fetch` then `merge`—had to do a real merge, instead of just a "fast forward".  So it makes commit `M`, the merge commit.  The `origin/master` label still refers to commit `E`, not `M`. You're now on `master` at commit `M`, which is a merge of `E` and `Z`.  You're "one ahead" of `origin/master`.

In either case, if you now run `git stash apply`, the stash script (it's a shell script that uses a lot of low level git "plumbing" commands) effectively<sup>2</sup> does this:

```
git diff stash^ stash > /tmp/patch
git apply /tmp/patch
```

This diffs `stash`, which names `w`—the "work tree" part of the stash—against the correct<sup>3</sup> parent.  In other words, it finds out "what you changed" between the proper parent commit (`C` or `Z`, as appropriate) and the stashed work-tree.  It then applies the changes to the currently-checked-out version, which is either `E` or `M`, again depending on where you started.

Incidentally, `git stash show -p` really just runs that same `git diff` command (with no `> /tmp/patch` part of course).  Without `-p`, it runs the diff with `--stat`.  So if you want to see in detail what `git stash apply` will merge in, use `git stash show -p`.  (This won't show you what `git stash apply` can attempt to apply from the index part of the stash, though; this is a minor gripe I have with the stash script.)

---

In any case, once the stash applies cleanly, you can use `git stash drop` to remove the reference to the stash-bag, so that it can be garbage-collected.  Until you drop it, it has a name (`refs/stash`, aka `stash@{0}`) so it sticks around "forever" ... except for the fact that if you make a *new* stash, the `stash` script "pushes" the current stash into the stash reflog (so that its name becomes `stash@{1}`) and makes the new stash use the `refs/stash` name.  Most reflog entries stick around for 90 days (you can configure this to be different) and then expire.  Stashes don't expire by default, but if you configure this otherwise, a "pushed" stash can get lost, so be careful about depending on "save forever" if you start configuring git to your liking.

Note that `git stash drop` "pops" the stash stack here, renumbering `stash@{2}` to `stash@{1}` and making `stash@{1}` become plain `stash`.  Use `git stash list` to see the stash-stack.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's not bad to go ahead and commit them anyway, and then do a later `git rebase -i` to squash or fixup further second, third, fourth, ..., nth commits, and/or rewrite the temporary "checkpoint" commit.  But that's independent of this.

<sup>2</sup>It's a fair bit more complex because you can use `--index` to try to keep staged changes staged, but in fact, if you look in the script, you'll see the actual command sequence `git diff ... | git apply --index`.  It really does just apply a diff, in this case!  Eventually it invokes `git merge-recursive` directly, though, to merge in the work tree, allowing the same changes to have been brought in from elsewhere.  A plain `git apply` would fail if your patch does something the "good stuff" commits `D` and `E` also does.

<sup>3</sup>This uses git's parent-naming magic syntax, with a little advance planning inside the `stash` script.  Because the stash is this funky merge commit, `w` has two or even three parents, but the stash script sets it up so that the "first parent" is the original commit, `C` or `Z`, as appropriate.  The "second parent" `stash^2` is the index state at the time of the commit, shown as `i` in the little hanging stash-bag, and the "third parent", if it exists, is unstaged-and-maybe-ignored files, from `git stash save -u` or `git stash save -a`.

Note that I assume, in this answer, that you have *not* carefully staged part of your work-tree and that you are *not* using `git stash apply --index` to restore the staged index.  By not doing any of this, you render the `i` commit pretty much redundant, so that we need not worry about it during the `apply` step.  If you *are* using `apply --index` or equivalent, and *have* staged items, you can get into a lot more corner cases, where the stash won't apply cleanly.

These same caveats apply, with yet more corner cases, to stashes saved with `-u` or `-a`, that have that third commit.

For these extra-hard cases, `git stash` provides a way to turn a stash into a full-fledged *branch*—but I'll leave all that to another answer.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've ever seen on SO, and your other answers appear equally complete. Thank you. One question though: when applying a stash, will git inform you of conflicts? (That is, of changes made in D or E that your stashed changes overwrite?)

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: the "apply" step (in fact, all of these kinds of things inside git) all use what I call the "merge machinery".  Only some commands expose the options (`--strategy` and `-X`), others use default settings; the defaults stop with an error on conflicts.  Of course, git can only tell you about conflicts *it* sees, so in general, you always have to inspect the results even if git is happy with them.

Comment: If `stash` goes back to latest HEAD I had fetched, why would I use `pull --rebase` as shown on some posts like http://stackoverflow.com/a/30209767/577052 ? There should be no changes left to rebase as they are als stashed, or are they not?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler: I do not understand the premise of the question (the "goes back to latest fetched HEAD" part). Stashing itself has nothing to do with `git fetch`; `git stash save` just creates several commits that are on no branch at all, then resets (with options, so not so simple here) the index and work-tree. Rebase has nothing to do with this either: `git rebase` *copies* commits. The commits to be copied are selected using the current branch. The destination for the new copies, and a limiter, come from arguments to `git rebase`, or from the current branch's upstream setting.

Comment: Where can I see the source code for the "stash script" that you mention?

Answer (score 7):

the stash git command remembers where the stash comes from:

```
   git stash list
```

out put

```
   stash@{0}: WIP on master.color-rules.0: 35669fb [NEW] another step toward initial cube
```

Where you can see on which SHA1 it was made on. So if you git stash, git pull, git stash apply and you got a conflict, the stash is not dropped (it will only if you drop or if the apply was successful). So you can always get the SHA1 from git stash list and

```
   git checkout 35669fb
   git stash apply
```

and it is garanteed to work. I recommend using the -b option and provide a branch name for that recovery.

That being said, my favorite workflow is to ALWAYS checkout under on new "personnal" name to avoid such problems

Comment: `git stash branch <newbranch>` combines all three steps (check out the version to which the stash applies, create new branch, and apply stash with `--index` and then drop stash after successful application).

Answer (score 1):

Generally uncommitted changes are always bad. Either your changes are good, then commit them, or they are bad than discard them. Doing any git operations while having uncommitted changes tends to cause trouble and git will not be able to help you, as git does not know about anything you did not commit.

Having said that, back to your question. ;)

Git is generally pretty smart. When you apply your stash, it tries to merge your changes with the other changes. Most of the time this just works.

If the changes really conflict, because you changed the same lines in a different way, git will tell you, and you will have to resolve the conflict by yourself. - Even in this case git will help you by having `git mergetool`, which will launch a suitable command to show you the conflicts and allows you to resolve them one by one.

Comment: Discussion (the first paragraph of this answer) is perhaps better fitted in the comments, not in an answer.