# How do I tell what branch I was on when I stashed changes?

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm aware of `git stash show -p stash@{0}` giving the log of changes saved into that stash entry, but I'd like to know what branch I was on when I made those changes. This would be very helpful for a number of scenarios:

- cleaning up my stash stack
- when returning to an old issue (and therefore old branch) for which I stashed the changes, thinking at the time I would be able to soon return to the issue and unstash, but ended up being pulled onto some other issue(s) for a very long time. I find myself thinking "I think I stashed changes for this, but am unsure and if so, which entry in the stash stack were they."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is shown with `git stash list`. In this example "on dude" shows branch dude and "on master" shows branch master.

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on dude: 7eb87fe initial
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 7eb87fe initial
```

Also, it sounds like you are stashing when you abandon work temporarily. I have another workflow that I think is superior to stashing, I commit it and then reset it. That way the change is on the branch and if I ever abandon that branch the related code is discarded as well.

```
# do some work on dev
git co -b dev
# temporarily abandon it
git commit -a -m'commit instead of stash'
# do other work on master
git co master
# lets resume the old work
git co dev
# un stash
git reset HEAD^
```

Comment: hey if you can move the workflow suggestion (which I do appreciate, I think i'll start doing it that way) to a comment, i'll mark the answer to the question as accepted.

Comment: There is no formatting in the comments so I think it's best left in the answer... Or I can remove it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

(Ideally this should be a comment, but it's way too big and needs too much formatting...)

Note that the branch name (stored as part of the default message) is just the name *at the time of the stash*.  If you have an old stash that you have been ignoring for a while, it's possible that the branch name has moved.  For instance:

```
$ git checkout -b hack
...
$ git stash   # creates "WIP on hack"
...
$ git branch -D hack # delete hack branch
...
$ git checkout -b hack
...
$ git stash list
```

The "WIP on hack" you'll see in the list is the *old* `hack` branch, not the new one.

The actual stash reference—the thing stored in `stash@{4}` or whatever the number is—points to a specific commit (the special peculiar merge commit that `git stash` saves, which I call a ["stash bag"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452)).  That commit has a parent commit, which has another parent, and so on; this chain of parents forms the actual branch structure within the commit graph that git keeps.  The branch *name* is just that: merely a name, something you can change at whim, or delete with `git branch -D hack` for instance, but the branch *structure* is permanent, at least as much as any git commit is permanent.  (Commits remain in the repository as long as they are "reachable" from some named starting point, such as `stash@{4}`.)

If, for instance, you have rebased the branch the stash was made on, the stash itself points to the *old* (un-rebased) branch structure:

```
                n - n   <-- hack
              /
* - * - * - *           <-- mainline
      \
        o - o           <-- [old hack when stash was made]
            |\
            i-w         <-- stash@{4}
```

Here, the stash-bag hangs off the last "old" commit `o`, while branch `hack`, which was rebased, now points to the last "new" commit `n`.

You can of course apply or pop the old stash-bag onto the new branch; that's how stashes are meant to work, more or less.  Or you can use `git stash branch` to convert the old stash into a new branch of its own: for instance, if you did:

```
git stash branch restore-hack stash@{4}
```

you would get this graph:

```
                n - n   <-- hack
              /
* - * - * - *           <-- mainline
      \
        o - o           <-- restore-hack
```

with the index now containing whatever it contained when you did the original `git stash`, and the work-tree set up the way it was when you did that same `git stash`.  (In other words, the "stash bag" has been unpacked into the index and work-tree.)  You can now `git add` and/or `git commit` to make more commits on the restored (old) `hack` branch, now named `restore-hack`.

If you find yourself with a lot of old saved stashes, you may wish to start doing real commits that are just intended to be reworked later (as Andreas Wederbrand suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24918295/1256452)).  I find they tend to be less confusing, myself, and with my need to rebase to pick up "upstream" changes, they just automatically rebase.