# Weird behavior with running git stash twice

Tags: git, git-stash

I had a few modified files in my develop branch and few that were newly created but untracked by git. I wanted to move these changes to a feature branch, So I ran `git stash`. 
After checking with `git status`, I realized that git did not stash the untracked files. So I ran `git stash -u`.

Something weird happened here, because after I checked out my feature branch and was trying to see the two stashed changes, using `git stash show stash@{0}` and `git stash show stash@{1}`, it did not show me anything for the 0th stash index and the 1st stash index showed the untracked files. There was no 2nd index.

`git stash list` did not show anything at all. I went ahead and did `git stash apply` and that only brought back the untracked file changes, not the modified files.

After I applied the untracked files changes, I ran `git stash show stash@{0}` and `git stash show stash@{1}` again. This time, the 0th index again was empty, and the modified files changes moved to the 1st index. Applying the stash@{1}, brought back all my changes, but I fail to understand the behavior of the stash. Has anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

For clarity:

```
$ git stash; git stash -u
```

This is two separate `git stash` commands.  Each one does a `git stash save` since there is no more-specific verb at the end.

The first `git stash` saved away both your current index and your current work-tree (by making two separate commits, neither of which is on a branch).  After that, your index matched the `HEAD` commit and your work-tree was clean, except of course for untracked files.

Normally, if you then tried to repeat `git stash save`, it would just tell you that there was nothing to save, and would do nothing, but for your second `save` you added the `-u` flag: save (and then remove) untracked files.  So this made a *second* stash, using your current index—which the first `save` made equal to the `HEAD` commit—and your current work tree—which, again, is equal to the `HEAD` commit—and using a third commit as part of the stash-bag: the `u` commit.  See the drawing in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452), but note that you have two separate stash bags hanging off the same (`HEAD`) commit, in your particular case.

When you save a stash with some active stash(es), the `stash` script uses git's "reflogs" to "push" the current stash into the "stash stack", making the new stash the top-most one, `stash@{0}`.  So your stash-bag with the `u` commit in it is, at this point, `stash@{0}`, while your stash with the modified-index-and/or-work-tree (and no `u` commit containing untracked files) is in `stash@{1}`.

You then did:

```
git checkout feature
```

or similar to change `HEAD` to point to a different branch.  Let's draw the situation now, by assuming that the stash was done on a branch named `X`:

```
... - o - o - o   <-- HEAD=feature
  \
    o - *         <-- X
        |\
        |  \
        |\   \
        i-w    \      <-- stash@{1}
                |\
                i-w   <-- stash@{0}
                 /
                u
```

Again, both stash-bags hang off commit `*`; the one in `stash@{1}` has the untracked files, but its `i` and `w` commits are identical to commit `*` itself.

You said:

> using `git stash show stash@{0}` and `git stash show stash@{1}`, it did not show me anything for the 0th stash index and the 1st stash index showed the untracked files ...

This seems unlikely.  However, if you wrote `git show stash@{0}` instead of `git stash show stash@{0}`, and `git show stash@{1}` instead of `git stash show stash@{1}`, this *is* what you would have seen, because `git show` shows merge commits as "combined diffs", and you were basically asking `git show` to look at the `w` commit in each stash-bag.  Each `w` commit *is* a merge commit, it's just not the usual kind of merge, so `git show` produces largely-useless results.

> I went ahead and did git stash apply and that only brought back the untracked file changes, not the modified files.

That is what would be expected: `git stash apply` (which applies `stash@{1}`) tells `git stash` to compare the work-tree and index commits (`w` and `i`) to their parent (commit `*`), and in the case of a three-parent stash-bag, to extract the files in the third parent (`u`).  There are no changes between `w` and `*` but this brings back `u`.

> Applying the `stash@{1}`, brought back all my changes ...

Again, this is to be expected: `git stash apply` tells `git stash` to compare the work-tree (for `stash@{1}`) and index commits to their parent (`*`).  Here, there *are* changes, and it extracts those and applies those to the new `HEAD` commit.  There is no third parent in this other stash-bag, so `apply` is finished at this point.

If you like the result, go ahead and `git stash drop` the two stash-bags.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to answer. But I did see the exact behavior I have explained, with the 0th index being empty and that is what stumped me.
I did not use `git show stash@{0}`, I used `git stash show stash@{0}` and the `git stash list` also did not show me any stashes.

Comment: I'd like to see actual cut-and-paste output, although by now probably you don't have the stashes any more.  In particular `git stash show` simply runs `git diff` between the base commit (the one marked `*` in this case) and the work-tree commit, so you should never see untracked files and showing stash 0 should be empty, while showing stash 1 should produce any work-tree changes (this would also be empty *if* you had `git add`-ed all your work, as all the changes would be in the index instead).

Comment: BTW if you *do* still have them, the output from `git stash list` should not be empty either, and whatever the output is (although "empty" is not much to work with :-) ), it could be useful in trying to figure out how this is happening.

Comment: No, I don't have them anymore. It wasn't even on my machine, it was happening on a colleague's machine. I was the one driving though. However, when I tried to reproduce on my machine, I couldn't get any of that behavior. I could see the stash list out both the stashes, and the 0th index wasn't empty in my case, either.