# Git Stash Failed

Tags: git, git-stash, smartgit

I am using SmartGit in Windows. Today I needed to do a hard reset back a couple commits. SmartGit automatically made a stash for me of my modified files.

After the reset, it tried to apply the stash:

```
$ git.exe stash apply --index stash@{0}
```

But it gave me:

```
Apply Stash: stash failed (return code 1)
```

I can view the stash contents and see all my code, but I can't apply the stash. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do `git stash pop`. It will get you your stashed changes in the working tree. (`pop` considering you want `stash@{0}`.

Answer (score 4):

Can you export it to a patch, and then try to apply manually?

```
git stash show -p > my_stash.patch
```

Comment: I will try that. Is a stash the same format as a patch?

Comment: No, but the -p will output a patch like format. Note that this patch will not include changes you already have in your working directory.

Answer (score 4):

There are several things you can do:

1. `git apply --index` tries to preserve the staged vs unstaged setup of the stash you're applying.  Often this is "too hard" but applying *without* `--index`, allowing all the changes to become unstaged, is possible.  If you don't need to maintain the separation, that may "just work".
2. As [acanby suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28554415/1256452), you can turn the stash into a patch.  Note that `git stash show` shows only the unstaged part of the stash, so this is somewhat like not using `--index` as well.
3. If all else fails, you can turn your saved stash into its own (new) branch.  This will resurrect all the commits you `reset`-away, but *only on that new branch*.  In essence,<sup>1</sup> what `git stash branch newbranch` does is:

   - turn the saved index in the stash into an ordinary commit
   - whose parent is the commit that was active (was the `HEAD` commit) when you did the `git stash save` step (and its parent is its same old parent, etc);
   - make the index-commit tip of the branch *`newbranch`*, which is a newly created branch; and
   - leave the work-tree and (if saved as part of the stash) untracked/all files ready for you to commit on the new branch you're now on.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's really "fact" more than "essence": this is how `git stash branch` works simply because it leaves the `i` commit of the [stash-bag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20586009/1256452) in place and makes a new branch-name pointing to it.