# git diff stash@{0} shows changes - git stash apply does not change the working tree

Tags: git, git-stash

#### The Problem

We had an external developer working on a project on a wrong branch through FTP (not working with git at all).

#### The fix

To reapply his (by nature, uncommitted) changes, I ran `git stash`, followed by `git checkout [correct_branch]`, then `git stash apply`. Nothing had changed except for a single file which was not changed by him (but existed in the stash anyway).

#### The good ol' weirdness

Running `git diff 'stash@{0}' [correct_branch] --name-only` (alternatively omitting the `name-only` flag) shows me a correct difflist of the changed files. When running `git stash apply` or `git stash apply 'stash@{0}'`, followed by `git diff` does not tell me that anything has changed.

What's going on here? The `diff` against the stash tells me that there is indeed changes in that stash that hasn't been applied to the current branch.

Comment: The `stash` ref points to the `w`ork-tree commit in what I have taken to calling a "stash bag": http://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452 - see that answer for what git does with the `i` and `w` commits during `git stash apply`, and note that `git diff stash@{0} branch` is comparing the `w` tree to that of branch-tip `branch`.  I don't see off-hand why your problem is occurring but it may be worth reading through that answer anyway.

Comment: That clarified some things about stashing, so thanks even though it didn't really solve my problem (as you said)! :)