# Want to apply my stash to a new branch and override everything in it with what is in my stash

Tags: git, git-stash, git-checkout

So i'm working in Git and trying to create a new branch where I can drop the contents of my stash, and favor my stash in any merge conflicts that occur when doing so. I am doing the following:

```
git checkout -b *newbranchname*
git stash apply
```

And it is telling me of merge conflicts in a file. How can I go about doing this in the terminal and automatically favor the stash in any conflicts without having to deal with them specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest method is "don't do that" :-)

Instead, turn your `git stash` contents into a branch of its own:

```
git stash branch newbr
```

Now you have a new branch `newbr`, with the index ready to commit (if you had items `git add`ed to the index) and the work-tree modified as per the stash, ready to be `git add`ed and committed.  If you had carefully added stuff before, go ahead and commit that now, then add everything else and commit again.  If not, just add everything now and commit.  Now you have a new branch `newbr` with one or two commits on it—how many depends on how many `git commit`s you just did—which joins up with whatever commit was in place when you did the `git stash`.

You can now make a different new branch from a different starting point, if that's what you want, and use `git cherry-pick` to bring over those commits, then discard the new branch.  Or, you can use `git rebase -i` (with the `<upstream>` and, optionally, `--onto` arguments) to copy the commits elsewhere in the usual rebase fashion, discarding the original commits once the copies are done.  Or, if the existing starting point of `newbr` is what you wanted after all, you are already all set.

---

All that said, if you really *do* want to just check out the work-tree version of conflicted files, completely ignoring the current version of those files, you can do that quite easily.  The thing to remember is that the reference name `stash` (or `stash@{N}` for some number *N*) refers to the `w`ork-tree commit that `git stash` made when it saved the `i` and `w` commits of the [stash bag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452).  Hence:

```
git checkout stash -- path/to/file
```

extracts the `w` version of `path/to/file`, writing it through the index (hence resolving any conflicted merge), completely ignoring the `HEAD` version of that file.

(The `i`ndex-commit versions of files are in `stash^2`, and if there is an untracked/all-files commit, those files are in `stash^3`, as I noted in [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452).  While `w` is technically a merge commit, it's not a normal merge, and the all-files commit in particular is very unusual, since it has *only* those files, and none of the index/work-tree files.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
git merge-recursive --theirs stash^ -- @ stash
```

to see if you like the results.