# How to show files(of staging area) in stash?

Tags: git

I am using git `1.7.1` . My scenario is something as described below:-

I have added 5 new files to my project and modified 1 existing file. I now decide the current changes to stash and move to some different branch. So, I add all new 5 files to staging area and then I stash it. Let `stash@{0}` be my stash. So in the stash `stash@{0}`, there are 5 new files in staging area and 1 modified file in the working directory.

Now I do a `git stash list`. It gives me say below list of stashes:

```
stash@{0}
stash@{1}
stash@{2}
stash@{3}
stash@{4}
stash@{5}
```

After a day or two, I came back and wanted to check the available list of stashes and then wanted to check which stash contains what. Therefore I tried, `git stash show -p stash@{0}` . This gives me the changes of only 1 file which I have modified in working directory. It doesn't give any info that there are 5 new files in the staging area. One way I could do is apply the stash to a branch and do a `git status`. That would give the desired output.

But what I am looking here is to get this info before applying a stash to any branch. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why don;t you get a newer version? Git is up to 2.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stash consists of two (or sometimes three) commits.  These commits are not on a branch, but rather are found through the special `stash` reference (`refs/stash`) and its reflog (`stash@{n}`, for any integer *n*, is a reflog name).  These two (or three) commits  hold the index/staging-area state, the work-tree state, and—if the third commit is present—the untracked files or the extra "all" files (from `git stash save -u` or `git stash save -a`).  I like to refer to these as the `i`, `w`, and `u` commits of a ["stash bag"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452), since if you draw these two (or three) commits as part of a commit-graph drawing, they look like a little bag hanging off a commit.

The `git stash show` command runs `git diff` to compare the `w` commit to its parent.  What you need is to compare the `i` commit (to `i`'s or `w`'s parent, marked `*` in the diagram below) instead.  There is no flag to `git stash show` to do this, but you can make use of the stash-bag's structure:

- The `stash` or `stash@{n}` reference points directly to to the `w` commit.
- The first parent of the `w` commit is the commit that was `HEAD` when the stash was saved.
- The `i` commit is the *second* parent of the `w` commit.  (This means that the `w` commit is a merge commit; but do not try to use it as a merge!)  The `i` commit has a single parent, which is the same parent as `w`'s first parent.
- If the `u` commit exists, it is the third parent of `w`, and it is itself a root commit (has no parent).

I find that the Unicode arrow characters do not display properly on all viewers so this diagram has the arrows drawn a bit larger:

```
...<-- o <-- o <-- * <-- o <-- o   <-- branch
                   ^
                   |\
                   | \
                   i<-w   <-- stash@{3}
```

In this diagram, commit `*` is the commit that *was* the `HEAD` commit when this stash was saved (but since then, there have been two more commits added to `branch`).

Git has some special syntax for going from any specific commit to its parents, as described in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), so you can get a diff comparing commit `w` to commit `*`:

```
git diff stash@{3} stash@{3}^
```

This is what `git stash show` does: `stash@{3}` names commit `w` and `stash@{3}^` names its parent, which is commit `*`.  But what you want is to compare commit `i` to commit `*`:

```
git diff stash@{3}^2 stash@{3}^
```

Note that you can also compare `i` and `w`, if you like, by naming `stash@{3}^2` (`w`'s second parent = `i`) and `stash@{3}` (`w` itself), in that order.

(As a shortcut, you can use `git show` on the `i` commit, since `git show` diffs a commit against its parent(s).  Note that using `git show` on `w` is less useful: `w` has two parents, so `git show` produces a *combined diff*, which is reasonable for regular merge commits, but rarely very useful for these `w` commits, since they are not normal merge commits.)

Comment: thanks much for your elaborate ans..... :) I am going through the links you provided as reference, and then will come back and ask you if I understood it or if I have some doubts!