# How Do I Get Back Untracked Files I Stashed with Git?

Tags: eclipse, git

I got an error that I couldn't do a `git pull` this morning because it would overwrite a file that I wasn't even using. It was an untracked file. I tried using `git stash`, then `git rm` neither would work on it. So I finally found out that I could use `git stash` with untracked files. So I did that, but it went above and beyond and got everything.

It deleted weeks worth of work even stuff that wasn't listed and is now causing it so I can't reopen Eclipse do to an issue with the `config.ini`. I tried using `stash pop`, but it doesn't get the untracked files.

This question specifically ask about untracked files, which is is different than a simple stash and pull.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Please add the output of `git status`, `git stash show stash{0}` (replace 0 with another number if that isn't the right stash), and maybe also `git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph`.

Comment: @ScottWeldon: typo: that should be `stash@{0}`.

Comment: Although it's long and technical, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20586009/1256452 may be helpful here.

Comment: Torek that worked.