# Run tests only for staged files: `git stash -k -u` and `git stash pop` will raise conflicts on partial staged files

Tags: git, git-stash

## tl;dr

I want to run tests only with staged files before commit:

1. `git stash save -k -u` to stash unstaged/untracked files/changes before testing
2. run tests with staged files
3. `git stash pop` to restore changes/files at step 1.

The problem is using `git stash pop` will raise conflicts on the files with partial staged. Resolving the conflicts will lead to lose the partial staged/unstaged changes (you need to pick partial lines to staged again).

> Update: If you want to know the shell script to run this procedure, please jump to the last section for more information.

### **NOTE: only adjacent lines (or close enough) with partial staged will cause this issue.** For example, if you have 6 new line changes in a file:

```
1 +| a     (add to staged)
2 +| b     (add to staged)
3 +| c     (add to staged)
4  | d     (keep unstaged)
5  | e     (keep unstaged)
6  | f     (keep unstaged)
```

Now use `git stash -k -u` and then `git stash pop` will raise conflict.

## Demonstrate the question

Git provides three phases for changes before commit: `staged`, `unstaged` and `untracked`.

Any changes will be added to `unstaged`. Before commit, you can pick some of lines or files and add them to `staged` by `git add`.

Now, after adding some of code to `staged`, I want to run tests with only staged files to make sure they were suitable for commit, so I need to stash `unstaged` and `untracked` changes (new files) by `git stash -k -u` and keep `staged` changes.

Say, for example, I have 3 file changes: file A is fully staged, file B is partial staged (some of code), and file C is a new file which is untracked.

```
[staged]
  file A
  file B (only stage some of code)
[unstaged]
  file B
[untracked]
  file C (new file)
```

After running `git stash -k -u`, all unstaged/untracked changes are stashed.

```
[staged]
  file A
  file B (only stage some of code)
[unstaged/untracked]
  <none, clean>
```

Here comes the problem. After running tests and then `git stash pop`, it raises conflicts on file B because it is partial staged. I'm sure that I did not change file B when stashing and testing.

I wonder how to auto-merge with `git stash pop` without any conflict just like before I stashed them.

## My workflow

I think this is a very usual workflow

```
  development start
          |
[make changes (unstaged)] 
          |
(pick changes to staged for commit by `git add`)<---|
          |                                         |
          V                     (pick other changes to fulfill tests)
[partial staged/unstaged]                           |
          |                                         |
(stash unstaged changes by `git stash -k -u`)       |
          |                                         |
(run tests only with staged files for commit)       |
          |                                         | 
(restore stashed files by `git stash pop`)          |
          |                                         |
          |------------<if test failed>-------------| 
          |
    <if test success>
          |
[commit staged files by `git commit`]
          |
          V
keep development or next commit
```

I need a way to `stash pop` without losing staged/unstaged state for all changes. Keeping staged files is very important to commit or fulfill test by adding other changes.

### Update with solution: a shell script to run the procedure

According to @torek's answer, I write a shell script to run tests with only staged files:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e

# stash all unstaged changes
# (-k: unstaged files; -u: new added files; -q: quite)
echo '--------------------------------------------------------------'
echo '---- Stash all unstaged/untracked files (git stash -k -u) ----'
echo '--------------------------------------------------------------'
BEFORE_STASH_HASH=$(git rev-parse refs/stash)
git stash -k -u -q
AFTER_STASH_HASH=$(git rev-parse refs/stash)
if [ "$BEFORE_STASH_HASH" == "$AFTER_STASH_HASH" ]; then
  echo '\n\n---- Stash failed! Please check and retry. ----\n\n';
  exit 1;
fi;

# run test only with staged files
echo '-------------------'
echo '---- Run tests ----'
echo '-------------------'
<run your tests here> ||      #### <=== replace your test command here
(echo '\n\n---- Tests failed! Please fix it before commit. ----\n\n')

# restore all stashed changes
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304610/
echo '-----------------------------------------------------------'
echo '---- Restore all stashed files (git stash pop --index) ----'
echo '-----------------------------------------------------------'
git reset --hard -q &&
git clean -df -q &&
git stash pop --index -q ||
(echo '\n\n---- Restore failed! Please check and fix it. ----\n\n')
```

Comment: Meta: this is a very well-assembled question — thank you for taking the time to use precise language, and for putting together the workflow diagram to make it easier for others to answer!

Comment: You can commit your staged changes before running tests and then revert it if the changes fail your tests.

Comment: @Paul, if failed, how to restore staged/unstaged changes?

Comment: It seems that `git stash pop` will trigger auto-merge anyway, but you cannot pass merge flags, such as `-s theirs` which would solve this issue. I'd like to point out that if the staged and unstaged changes in the same file are not close enough to conflict, the auto-merge will resolve normally - I think this is not clear by the term "partial staged" from the question, and I think this used to fail too in older git versions.

Comment: @AndréSassi, yes, only adjucent lines in both staged/unstage will lead to conflict after `git stash -k -u` and `git stash pop`. Using `git checkout --theirs -- .` to solve the conflict will still remain the file in `unmerged` state (needs `add`/`reset`) not `unstaged` state.

Comment: @李岡諭 You stash unstaged changes before testing, right? If you need to revert, you do `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, your latest commit is discarded and changes from it become staged changes. Then you do `git stash pop` and you stashed changes become non-staged changes.

Comment: @Paul, OK, I succeed to keep partial staged/unstaged states for the same file using your strategy. I'll write an answer, but it may not the best approach.

Comment: There are several intertwining issues here arising from `--keep-index` and `--include-untracked`. Note that `git stash` makes *three* commits in this case: one for index state, one for work-tree state, and a third to hold the untracked files. Restoring the stash state requires re-resetting and cleaning. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586009/how-to-recover-from-git-stash-save-all for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer—see [How to recover from "git stash save --all"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586009/how-to-recover-from-git-stash-save-all) for more—but while this is an appealing process, and it will work once the bug in `git stash` gets fixed, it is a bit dangerous today.

If you have fixed the bug, or don't mind living slightly dangerously, :-) you can use this process:

1. Run `git stash save -k -u` *and make sure it saves something* (e.g., compare the results from `git rev-parse refs/stash` before and after).
2. Run your tests.
3. `git reset --hard && git clean -df` (optionally, including `-q` for both).  The `git reset --hard` is needed only if the tests modify committed files, and the `git clean` is needed only if the tests create untracked files.
4. Run `git stash pop --index`.  Note that the `--index` is critical here.  You may wish to use `-q` as well.

Instead of `save` and `pop --index`, you might want to use `create` and `apply --index` and store your stash-bag under a different reference (that you manipulate and/or delete when done, in whatever way you like).  Of course, if you're going to go this far, you might want to write your own modified `git stash` script that avoids the current one's bug in the first place.

---

There's a completely different, and to my mind simpler, approach to running tests:

1. Create an empty temporary directory.
2. Turn the current index into a tree, then read that tree into the temporary directory.  (Or use `git checkout-index` to extract the index into the temporary directory.  In either case, note the environment variables `GIT_WORK_TREE` and `GIT_DIR`, or the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` arguments to the front end `git` command.)
3. Run the tests in the temporary directory.
4. Discard the temporary directory.

This avoids the `git stash save` bug and, with a slight modification to step 2, lets you test any revision.  There are two obvious disadvantages: you need a place to store a temporary tree, and the temporary tree is not where the work-tree is.  How much of a problem those are depends on your repository and your tests.

Comment: Awesome. I don't know using `git stash -k -u` will still stash staged (indexed) files and I can restore them. This approach is better than using temporal `git  commit` to keep staged files.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, here is a workaround provided by @Paul. I write this here, but I'm still looking for a better solution.

These are the steps:

1. Use `git stash -k -u` to stash unstaged/untracked files but keep staged files for commit.
2. Run tests with staged files. **If failed, go to step 3; if passed, go to step 4.**
3. If failed, you need to restore unstaged/untracked files back and add new code to staged state. Here is the workaround for my problem:

   - Run **`git commit -m 'temp'`** to store staged files in a new commit temporally.
   - Run **`git stash pop`** to restore unstaged/untracked files. It still will raise conflict for adjacent line changes between commit (previous staged) and unstaged.
   - Run **`git checkout --theirs -- . && git reset`** to resolve the conflicts, if any, and reset `unmerged` state to `unstaged` state. Because previous staged files are now committed, `git reset` will not influence them.
   - Run **`git reset HEAD^ --soft`** to rollback files in the latest commit to `staged` state.
   - Now you have the same file state (staged/unstaged/untracked) as before step 1. You can add other code from `unstaged` to `staged` to fulfill the requirement for tests. Maybe there is one git command to achieve those steps above which I'm looking for.
4. If passed, just `git commit` with the message and start the next iteration of development.

**Another approach** is: (1) just commit staged files first, (2) run test on the latest commit, and (3) patch the commit, if needed, by `git commit --amend` until passing the tests. I would not prefer this approach, because any interruption to your work might make you forget to resume patching the commit for passing tests, and push or publish the wrong commit.

Answer (score 0):

This flow works perfectly for me, including with partially staged files. I don't modify files in step 2.

```
# 1. Stash all changes, then discard all unstaged changes
$ git stash --include-untracked --keep-index

# 2. Run tests, run linter, check types, etc. Don't modify files. Commit if desired.

# 3a. If no commit was made, restore to initial state
$ git stash pop

# 3b. If a commit was made, restore unstaged changes
$ git checkout stash -- . ; git stash pop ; git reset
```

Useful aliases in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  stash-unstaged = stash --keep-index --include-untracked

  restore-unstaged = "!git checkout stash -- . ; git stash pop ; git reset"

  # Shortcuts
  stun = stash-unstaged
  restun = restore-unstaged
```

(Note that the alias `stash-unstaged` isn't quite accurate, because the stash also includes the index. But it's a convenient shorthand.)

With aliases, the commands are quite simple:

1. `git stash-unstaged`
2. Run tests, linting, etc.
3. `git stash pop` or `git restore-unstaged`, depending on whether a commit was made