# Why does git stash creates 2 commit objects? Seems like 1 was adequate

Tags: git, git-commit, git-stash

When doing `git stash` 2 commits are created. One is referenced by the `stash` ref and has 2 parent commits. One parent is the index of where we did the stash. The other parent has the actual contents of what we stashed.
Why are 2 commits needed for the stash? It seems to me that only 1 was sufficient. I.e. just make `stash` ref to the commit that has the actual contents.
Would this not work?

Answer (score 10):

`git stash` will, in fact, make up to *three* commits.  The two that you have observed are the default two: one for the *index* state—remember that in Git, the index, also called the *staging area*, contains the *next* commit to write, and is updated every time you `git add` new contents—and one for the *work-tree* state.  These may differ from each other and/or from the `HEAD` commit at the time you create the stash.

The fundamental issue is that `git stash` is not meant only to save your current work-tree, nor only to save your current index state, nor only to save some combination of the two.  If you intended to save the current index state, you could simply make an ordinary commit.  If you intended to save a combination of the two, you could simply run `git commit -a`.

Instead, `git stash` defaults to saving *both* the index state *and* the work-tree state, separately.  This allows you to retrieve both separate states again later, *if* that's what you mean to do.  It allows you to retrieve a mashed-together version of both states, *if* that's what you mean to do.  And, if you use `-u` or `-a`, so that `git stash` makes its *third* commit containing untracked or untracked-and-ignored files, it allows you recover all those various states.

You express your final intent not at the time you *save* the stash, but rather at the time you *recover* it.<sup>1</sup>  This may not be the best possible design, since (a) sometimes it's not possible to recover your intended state, and (b) if you use `git stash pop` without `--index` when you *had* intended to use `--index`, this destroys the separated state and then discards both commits, making it exceedingly difficult to recover.  In general, though, deferring decisions is usually a good approach.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you use `--keep-index` at the time you save the stash, you are in fact asserting at least some intent at save-time.  But that's another matter entirely.  Moreover, there's a long-standing bug in `git stash` that makes keeping both index and work-tree state separate problematic.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452) for details.

Comment: I don't see 3 commits. I see only 2 commits. If I did stash save on master at commit `A` I see ref/stash pointing to `C` which has parents `A` and `B` and `B` is a loose object that has the contents that I committed with the commit msg: `index on master: A`. From these 3 it seems to me that `C` is redudant and ref/stash could might as well point to `B`. Am I not understanding your point?

Comment: See the third paragraph: only with `-u` or `-a` do you get that third commit. It's true that if either the index or work-tree commits match each other, or one matches the commit from which the stash-bag will dangle, then one of those commits is redundant—but the point is that the `stash` script saves both, intentionally, in case you intend to restore them separately later. Try `git add`-ing some change, then modifying the same file again, and then stashing—or use `git add -p` to add just *part* of some changed file, and then stash.

Comment: @Jim: I expanded the first paragraph somewhat (now I see I should trim the third :-) to match).