# How can I retrieve the content of a specific stashed file after have pull the new version of my project form GIT?

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull, git-stash

I am not so into GIT and I have the following problem.

I have some uncommitted file in my project that I have stashed by this statment:

```
git stash
```

Then I have pull the repository taking the work of a coolegue, that seems have correctly overwrite the changes of my stashed file.

Now I want to retrieve the content of a specific stashed file without lose the modification of my collegue.

I don't want to override the pulled version but only access to the code of the stashed version of a specific file.

Performing **git stash list** I obtain:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: fd2a59b First version of iterate/aggregate for data received from dataservice
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 4910263 DSS project added
```

How can I do it from the shell?

Answer (score 6):

Solved by myself:

1) First show the stashed file using the **git stash show** statment:

```
$ git stash show
 glis-toolkit/src/main/synapse-config/api/glisTest2.xml | 8 ++++++++
 1 file changed, 8 insertions(+)
```

2) Then I save this stashed version (from the stash 0) in another backup file by:

```
$ git show stash@{0}:glis-toolkit/src/main/synapse-config/api/glisTest2.xml  >  glisTest2Bck.xml
```

Comment: Are you sure about `git show stash@{0}:glis-toolkit/src/main/synapse-config/api/glisTest2.xml  >  glisTest2Bck.xml`? I tried it myself and I got an error `is not a stash-like commit`. What's your git version? (mine is 2.2.1)

Comment: It works fine for me !!! have you check that you have a {0} stash in your stash list (git stash list)?

Comment: Note that there is a significant difference between `git show` and `git stash show` (I put this here for anyone who comes by here later; I'll add an actual answer as well).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible to display the diff of a specific file into a stash easily.

However, to display the stashed code of `stash@{0}`

```
git stash show stash@{0} -p
```

If you're not satisfied with the output of the previous command, and since your working tree is clean, you can start by getting the wanted stash

```
# say you want to see diff of file my/file1.txt in stash{0}
git stash pop stash@{0}

# To Check your file by showing the diff between your work and your collegue's
git diff my/file1.txt
```

To go back to the first step

```
git stash
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Note that there is a fairly significant difference between `git show` and `git stash show`. Usually one would want the latter, not the former (i.e., your example is more likely what a user wants).

Answer (score 1):

There are several parts to this answer, because using `git stash` can be surprisingly difficult.  The way you used it in this case is correct for your use-case but there are many traps here for the unwary and the new-to / not-so-into Git folks.

#### Stash makes several commits

The main thing to know, from which everything else flows, is this: `git stash` makes commits.  In fact, it makes at least *two* commits; if you tell it to (with `-u` or `-a`) it makes a third commit.  **All of these commits are on *no* branch,** but they are still commits, and hence behave like commits.  The *format* of these commits is that they look, to other Git commands, like a bizarre kind of *merge commit*, which means in general that you want to keep other Git commands from looking too closely at them, and mostly use `git stash` to deal with them.

#### The index and work-tree, and `git checkout`

What `git stash` commits are the *index* and the *work-tree*.  The work-tree is the easiest to explain, by far: Git stores files in an internal, Git-only format, so to *work* with the files, you need a place where they are stored in the normal computer format.  That's the work-tree.  You can put, in this work-tree, files that are *not* going to be stored in Git as well, and this is where the *index* first comes in.

Git's index has several uses, but this is the main one: it is "where you build the next commit".  That is, you start out, in any Git repository, with a current commit that you ran `git checkout` to get.  (On the first `git clone`, Git runs `git checkout master` for you.  Well, it's *usually* `master` anyway, but it's definitely *something* checked out.)  This picks a branch name, uses it to find the *tip* commit of the branch, and makes that branch and that commit your *current* branch and commit.  Then it fills the index—which *was* completely empty, the very first time—from that particular commit, so now the index has in it all the files that are in the current (or `HEAD`) commit.  When adding these files to the index, Git also copies them into the work-tree, and so now you have the HEAD commit equal to the index which is equal to the work-tree.

If you now `git checkout` some other branch/commit, Git changes `HEAD` to account for the new branch and tip commit, *removes* the old files (for the previous HEAD) from the index and work-tree, *adds* the *new* files to the index and work-tree, and once again you have the HEAD commit equal to the index which is equal to the work-tree.

Note that in all of this shuffling-about, any file that is in the work-tree that is *not* in the index, goes untouched.  These are your *untracked* files, and that's what it means for a file to be untracked: **A file is tracked if and only if it is in the index.**  (This only has a little to do with `git stash` itself, but it's crucial to using Git and `.gitignore`, because `.gitignore` has no effect on a *tracked* file.)

To make a new commit yourself, you first modify a file in the work-tree, then use `git add` to copy the new version *into* the index.  This makes the new file ready to be committed, with the data it has right at the time you run `git add`.  This leaves all the existing index files the way they are, so the new commit will still have all the other files unchanged.  To add a file that isn't already in the index, you create it in the work-tree and again run `git add`.  The copies the file into the index, just as before, but this time it's not overwriting an existing copy.  To *delete* a file, you run `git rm`, which removes it from *both* the index *and* the work-tree.

This process of adding (overwriting existing or adding new) files to the index, and removing files from both index-and-work-tree, is what we mean when we say *staging* files for commit.  This is why the index is also called "the staging area": it's where we copy the updated work-tree files into, to get them staged.  Note that unless you `git rm` everything, the index itself is never actually *empty:* it's just that once you `git commit` the index, the index and the *new* commit you made, now match.  (This makes the `--allow-empty` flag to `git commit` a bit misleading.)

#### Back to `git stash`, specifically the "save new stash" sub-command

Again, `git stash save` makes (at least) two commits: first, it commits the index itself—which is really easy since that's how Git *always* makes commits—and then it makes a second commit that consists, in effect, of `git add`ing all the tracked work-tree files, i.e., copying them into the index, and then committing again.  For internal reasons, though, it makes this second commit as a *merge commit*, merging `HEAD` and the index commit it just made.  **We don't have to care as long as we use `git stash` to deal with this weird merge.**  It's only if and when we step outside `git stash` that we suddenly have to care about it.

After `git stash` makes those commits, it mostly does the equivalent of `git reset --hard HEAD`, although here again there are flag options to change this.  (For much—perhaps too much—more about this process, see [How to recover from "git stash save --all"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20586009/1256452))  What `git reset --hard HEAD` does is to re-set (hence `git reset`) three things:

1. It moves (i.e., re-sets) the current branch from its current commit to the specified new commit.  Because the specified new commit is `HEAD`, which *is* the current commit, this is like trying to drive from your kitchen to your kitchen: you may scurry around for a while, but you just end up exactly where you started.
2. It re-sets the index.  That is, it makes the index match the `HEAD` commit.  This un-stages all your staged changes, un-removing `git rm`-ed files, un-adding any totally-new-files, and recovering from the `HEAD` commit any files you modified and then staged.
3. It re-sets the work-tree.  That is, it makes all *tracked* files in the work-tree match their versions in the HEAD commit and (now) the index.

**As a kind of mental short cut, though, you can think of this as "ream out the index and work-tree".  The `stash` code just *saved* them both, as commits, so it's now safe to clean them out.**  Now the index and work-tree both look like they would if you had just freshly run `git checkout` on the current commit.  This is why you are now ready to use `git merge` or `git rebase` (whether or not you run it from `git pull`—remember, `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by merge or rebase, in all of these cases).

#### Applying the stash

The process of applying (or "popping") a stash can be *more* complicated than the process of saving it, but in *practice*, it tends to be simple.  Well, except when it goes wrong, anyway.  You just get to a (usually clean) commit-and-index-and-work-tree state as before, and run:

```
git stash apply
```

What this does is run a couple of `git diff` commands, to find out:

- What's the difference between the saved index, and the commit that was current when `git stash save` saved that index?
- What's the difference between the saved work-tree, and the commit that was current when `git stash save` saved that work-tree?

Usually, for each file, there's at most *one* difference (either via the saved index, or via the saved work-tree): you either staged the file, so the difference shows up in the saved index, or you didn't, so any changes you made show up in the saved work-tree (if there are *no* changes there's no difference at all).  Git then kind of smashes these all together, for each file, and puts all the changes into your current work-tree.  Your current *index* goes un-affected, by default, although there are fancier ways to `git stash apply`.

Once you are satisfied that the stash has applied correctly, you can run `git stash drop`.  This discards the two saved commits (and if `git stash save` "pushed" an earlier stash into `stash@{1}`, effectively "pops" the rest back down so that the earlier stash is now `stash@{0}`, or just `stash`).

**If you're sure you want to toss the stash after applying it, without first checking for correctness,** you can use `git stash pop`.  This literally just turns into `git stash apply && git stash drop` internally.  (Of course, it passes the specific stash through, if you're using `git stash pop stash@{n}`.)

#### Some hard cases, like XML files

The process of applying each change—each `git diff` from commit-that-was-HEAD-at-the-time, to saved index or saved work-tree—uses Git's full merge powers.  This is a simple(ish) mechanical process, but it works surprisingly well for most files.  XML files, unfortunately, tend to defeat Git's not-exactly-super powers.

In this case, you may want to do exactly what you did here.

Because `git stash save` simply makes two commits (that are not on a branch), you can use all the usual Git tools to deal with these two commits.  But once you do so, you must be careful, because the work-tree commit *looks like* a merge commit.  (Well, in fact, it *is* a merge commit.)  Fortunately, `git show <commit>:<path>` doesn't care if the commit is a merge: it just extracts the saved version of the file.

Each `stash` name or reflog name points to the saved work-tree commit.  Hence:

```
git show stash:path/to/file.xml
```

prints the saved work-tree contents of that file.  Redirecting that to a new file in your work-tree gives you a chance to examine the saved contents.  So this is a fine thing to do.

Watch out, though, for `git show stash`.  For those of us with dyslexia,<sup>1</sup> it's really easy to use this instead of `git stash show`.  But `git show <commit>` *does* care if the `<commit>` is a merge commit.  While `git stash show` knows to treat the work-tree commit as a separate, non-merge-y commit, `git show`—which sees `stash` as a commit ID, which then works but gets you the work-tree commit—tries to treat it as a merge commit.  It tries to show a *combined diff*, which often just ends up showing nothing at all.  (The most confusing case occurs when it *does* show something, but not *all* of what you stashed, which happens when you first staged a file, then modified it again in the work-tree.)

**TL;DR summary** (if it's not too late): `git show stash:path/to/file` is OK, but `git show stash` is always a mistake.  Mostly you want `git stash apply`, but for odd cases, `git show stash:path/to/file` will get you the saved *work-tree* version.  And, for really complicated cases, see [my other longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452) and consider using `git stash branch`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Dyslexics of the world untie!