# Difference between `git stash show -p stash@{N}` and `git show stash@{N}`?

Tags: git, git-stash, git-show

I thought they should be basically the same, but when I tried

```
$ git stash show -p stash@{N}
```

and

```
$ git show stash@{N}
```

the latter shows some additional commit information, but the actual diff was much, much shorter. (The former shows about a dozen files, but the latter only one.)

So, what exactly is the difference between the two and why are they different?

Can I also rely on things like `git diff stash@{M} stash@{N}` to be correct?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Stash bags

The thing saved by `git stash` is what I have taken to calling a ["stash bag"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412685/1256452).  It consists of two<sup>1</sup> separate commits: the "index" commit (the staging area), and the "work tree" commit.  The work-tree commit is a funny kind of merge commit.

Let me draw this again here (see the referenced answer for a much longer version), just to illustrate it properly.  Let's assume for simplicity that you have a small repo with just one branch and three commits on it, `A` through `C`.  You're on the one branch and make a few changes and then run `git stash save` (or just plain `git stash`).  This is what you get:

```
A - B - C     <-- HEAD=master
        |\
        i-w   <-- the "stash"
```

Now you might make (or switch to) another branch, but for illustration, let's just say you leave that stash there and make more "regular" commits on `master`:

```
A - B - C - D - E    <-- HEAD=master
        |\
        i-w   <-- stash
```

The point here is that the "stash-bag", the pair of `i`ndex and `w`ork-tree commits, is still hung off the same commit as it was before.  Commits cannot be changed, and this is true of stash-bag commits too.

But now you make a *new* stash by making some changes (while still on `master`) and running `git stash save` again.

What happens to the old stash-bag?  The "reference name"<sup>2</sup> `stash`, now points to the *new* stash-bag.  But the old stash-bag commits are still in there.  They just now require a "reflog" style name, `stash@{1}`.<sup>3</sup>

Anyway, what you have now is this:

```
A - B - C - D - E     <-- HEAD=master
        |\      |\
        i-w     i-w   <-- stash
          .
           -------------- stash@{1}
```

(When you use `git stash drop`, the stash script simply manipulates the reflog for the `stash` ref to delete the ID of the dropped stash-bag.  That's why all the "higher" ones get renumbered.  The actual stash-bag itself is garbage collected on the next `git gc`.)

This next bit is a key to understanding what's going on.

#### Any time git needs you to name a specific commit, you can do it any of many different ways.

Each commit has a "true name" that is the big ugly SHA-1 hash you see, values like `676699a0e0cdfd97521f3524c763222f1c30a094`.  You can write that.  It always means the same commit.  Commits can never be changed, and that's a cryptographic hash of the entire contents of the commit, so if that particular commit exists at all, that value is always its name.

It's not a good name for people, though.  So we have aliases: things like branch and tag names, and relative names like `HEAD` and `HEAD~2`, and reflog-style names like `HEAD@{yesterday}` or `master@{1}`.  (There's a command, `git rev-parse`, that turns name strings like this into hash values.  Try it: run `git rev-parse HEAD`, `git rev-parse stash`, and so on.  Most things in git use either `git rev-parse` or its big brother that does a lot more, `git rev-list`, to turn names into the SHA-1 values.)

(For a complete description of how to name a revision, see [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  Git uses SHA-1s for more than just commits, too, but here let's just think about commits.)

#### Git stash show, git show, and git diff

OK, finally, we can get to your `git show` vs `git stash show`, and `git diff` and so on.  Let's tackle `git stash show` first as that's the one you are *supposed* to use with stashes.  Moreover, the `git stash` sub-commands will verify that the commit you name—or, if you name no commit, the one found via the `stash` reference—"looks like" a stash, i.e., is one of these funny merge commits.

If you run `git stash show -p`, git shows you a diff (`-p`atch).  But what exactly is it showing?

Go back to the diagram with the stash-bags.  Each stash-bag is hung off a *specific* commit.  Above, the "main" stash is now hanging from commit `E`, and the `stash@{1}` earlier stash is hanging from `C`.

What `git stash show -p` does is compare that stash's work-tree commit, the `w`, against the commit from which the stash hangs.<sup>4</sup>

You can of course do this yourself.  Let's say you want to compare the `w` in `stash`, which hangs off commit `E`, against commit `E`, which can be named by the branch-name `master`.  So you can run: `git diff master stash`.  Here the name `stash` refers to the (current) stash commit `w`, and `master` refers to commit `E`, so this produces the exact same patch as `git stash show -p stash`.  (And, if you want to compare the `w` in `stash@{1}` against commit `C`, you just need to run `git diff` such that you name those two commits.  Of course it's easier to just `git stash show -p stash@{1}`.)<sup>5</sup>

What about plain `git show`?  This is a little more complicated.  `git show` is happy to show a commit, and you gave it a `stash` reference (either `stash` itself, or one of the reflog variants).  That's a valid commit identifier, and it resolves to one of the `w` work-tree commits in one of the stash-bags.  But `git show` acts differently when it sees a *merge* commit.  As the documentation says:

> It also presents the merge commit in a special format as produced by `git diff-tree --cc`.

So `git show stash@{1}` shows you a "combined diff", assuming that commit `w` is a normal merge of commits `C` and `i`, producing `w`.  It's not a normal merge after all, although a combined diff *may* actually be useful, provided you know what you're looking at.  Read the `--cc` documentation under `git diff-tree` to see how that works in detail, but I'll note that `--cc` implies `-c` which includes this bit:

> ... lists only files which were modified from all parents.

In the case of a `stash`, if you've `git add`-ed files before running `git stash`, so that the `i`-vs-`w` diff is empty, you won't see those files in the output here.

Last, if you `git diff stash@{M} stash@{N}`: this is just asking `git diff` to compare the different `w`ork-tree commits.  How much meaning that has, depends on what you're comparing, which will generally depend upon where the stash-bags are attached.

---

<sup>1</sup>Two or three, really, but I'm going to draw it as two.  You get two commits with `git stash save` (or a plain `git stash`, which means `git stash save`).  You get three commits if you add the `-u` or `-a` options to save untracked or all files.  This affects stash restoration, but not the output from the `git stash show` command.

<sup>2</sup>A "reference name" is just a name, rather like a branch or tag name.  There are many possible forms of reference name.  Branches and tags are just names with special purposes.  "Remote branches" are another form of these references, and "stash" is a reference as well.

In fact, `HEAD` is just another reference, although it's a *very* special reference.  I's so important that if you remove the `HEAD` file, git will decide that your repository is no longer a repository after all.

With some special-case exceptions—`HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, and so on—references all start with the string `refs/`.  Branches start with `refs/heads/`, tags start with `refs/tags/`, and "remote branches" start with `refs/remotes/`.  In other words, references have a "name space", generally starting with `refs/` and then getting another word underneath that to identify where they live.

The stash reference is spelled `refs/stash` (and stops there, there is no `refs/stash/jimmy_kimmel` or anything like that).

<sup>3</sup>In fact, this really *does* use the reflog.  This means, among other things, that stashes other than the "main" one, `refs/stash`, <s>will</s> can expire.  (Fortunately, as [musiphil notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738579/difference-between-git-stash-show-p-stashn-and-git-show-stashn/21743193?noredirect=1#comment34315394_21743193), the default since git 1.6.0 is that these *don't* expire; you must configure expiration times for them to make this happen—which is probably not what you want anyway.)

<sup>4</sup>The clever *way* it does this, using the suffix `^` notation, is spelled out in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412685/1256452).

<sup>5</sup>What if you want to look at the `i`ndex-commits in these stash bags?  Ah, good question! :-)  The stash script does not have a good answer.  The easy way to see these is to use the `^2` suffix to name the second parent of each stash, which is the `i` commit.  And, if you have a stash with a third commit containing untracked or all files, that's the third parent: commit `w` looks like a three-parent merge and `stash^3` gets at the third one.  But again, `w` is not a normal merge, so it's tricky.  Probably the best easy way to look at all the parts of a stash is to turn it into its own separate branch, using `git stash branch`.

Comment: That's an incredibly detailed answer.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Regarding "stashes other than the "main" one, `refs/stash`, will expire, the same way all reflog entries expire": [GIT v1.6.0 Release Notes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.6.0.txt) says, "By default, stash entries never expire. Set reflogexpire in [gc "refs/stash"] to a reasonable value to get traditional auto-expiration behaviour back".

Comment: @musiphil: Ah, good to know.  There are new controls in newer git versions for other refs as well, but for some reason I'd missed this.

Comment: Shouldn't `git diff stash master` be `git diff master stash` to produce the exact same patch as `git stash show -p stash`?

Comment: @musiphil: indeed!  Will fix.

Comment: @torek: In the past, I've been frustrated by `git stash pop` failing to preserve my index. Having read through the details in your answer, especially regarding that there are *two* commits stored, I have taken a closer look at stashes. I 'discovered' `git stash pop --index`, which "tries to reinstate not only the working tree’s changes, but also the index’s ones". I wish I'd realised that before. Thanks for the pointers in the right direction.

Comment: @torek: further to that, I tried viewing a `git stash save --include-untracked` (`-u`) using `gitk --all` where I'd set up all four combinations of indexed and not-indexed modifications and added files. I see in that case there seem to be *3* (*three*) commits stored: the extra commit in this case contains the untracked files.

Comment: @Rhubbarb: see footnote 1, which mentions the third commit for -u/-a.

Comment: @musiphil for `git diff master stash ` I am having `fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` error

Comment: @alper: if `stash` is an "unknown revision", you must not have any stashes now: `git stash drop` deletes the last one by deleting `refs/stash` entirely, after which you'd get this error. Or, if you'd never made one in the first place, you would also get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to a quirk where git stashes the working directory & index separately.
`git stash show -p stash@{N}` will show all changes in the stash, including those added to the stage.  However `git show stash@{N}` will not include changes that had been staged prior to stashing.  It seems the `git stash` command is smart enough to combine them together, whereas `git show` is simply showing you the contents of blob `stash@{0}`

And yes, `git diff stash@{M} stash@{N}` will work as you expect.

Comment: `git stash show -p` looks only at the work-directory version, completely ignoring the index version.  In most stash situations this doesn't matter, but if you `git add` a bunch of stuff and then mostly-revert the work tree copies, the output from `git stash show` can be pretty misleading, actually.  It's one of the things I'm not really happy with, in the stash script.  (But there are no obvious fixes for it, otherwise no doubt they'd already be in there. :-) )  (Also I say "mostly-revert" because if you get the work tree versions exactly back in sync with HEAD you hit a bug in `stash`.)

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response in the other answer, but for a quick TL;DR, this answer here gave me what I needed to know in terms of the key differences around staged/not staged before stash effects. Thanks! (im assuming its an accurate explanation? yes...?)