# git stash reporting: '' is not a stash reference

Tags: git, git-stash

Not quite sure what's happened, but git stash seems to be in a bad place.

```
% git stash list
stash@{0}: filter-branch: rewrite
stash@{1}: filter-branch: rewrite
stash@{2}: On mysolr: start mysolr stuff
```

Is OK, and `git show stash@{0}` works fine.  But:

```
% git stash drop
'' is not a stash reference
% git stash pop
'' is not a stash reference
% git stash drop stash@{0}
'stash@{0}' is not a stash reference
```

I've used git stash plenty in the past and not come across this.  I had recently rewritten history to remove a file from history before publishing to github.  The command I ran then was

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch FILENAME' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Any ideas how to fix the stash?

Comment: That should have worked, does `git reflog stash` look ok?

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík: Yes `git reflog stash` looked fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think `filter-branch` has broken your stashes.  If the argument to `git stash` does not sufficiently resemble a [stash bag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412685/1256452), you get that `not a stash reference` complaint.

Note that `git show stashref` uses plain old `git show`, which does not require that a commit given as an argument resemble a stash.  If `git stash show` fails the same way as the other `git stash` commands, or if manual examination of the stash in question shows that it's no longer a two- or three-parent merge commit, then this is in fact the case.

It was likely the `--prune-empty` that did it here.  If you had not `add`ed anything at the time of the stash, the index commits would be empty.  In general it's probably wiser to avoid filtering stash refs.

You can try two different approaches:

- Recover the original stash SHA-1(s) from `refs/original/` (where `filter-branch` left them) and/or reflogs; use those to rebuild `refs/stash` and/or the stash reflogs, or use them directly and then clobber the stash ref and its reflog.
- Use just the remaining work-tree commits in the rewritten stashes.  All you really need, since the index commits were empty, is that one work-tree commit.  You can get a patch using the `git show` command you've already run.

(For a bit more on stash and stash bags, including the three-parent form used with `--all` or `--untracked`, see [How to recover from “git stash save --all”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452).)

Assuming you have gotten your contents back and wish to wipe out the `stash` reference entirely, this will do it.  Note that this is the ["nuke it from orbit"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/nuke-it-from-orbit) option—don't do it until you're sure you're ready:

```
git update-ref -d refs/stash
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I managed to get commit ids from `git reflog stash` and then I managed to `git stash apply stash@{2}`.  Once I committed that I used the nuke from orbit option and I'm happy again.  Thank you.

Comment: `git update-ref -d refs/stash` is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: A much simpler `git stash clear` worked for me, even if I had the same error.

Comment: Not too surprising; `git stash clear` should do the equivalent "nuke from orbit" thing.  You lose all your old stashes either way...

Comment: i found the stash commit from refs/original/ , and than just cherry picked on my branch :O dont know yet if that had any side effects , but code looks great :)

Comment: @almaruf: if filter-branch pruned an empty one of the `i-w` pair, the other one should work fine as a cherry-pick.  In general you should be able to `git apply` the original directly though.

Answer (score 7):

You don’t have to nuke all of your stashes. You can delete just the broken ones manually using `git reflog`. In your case:

```
git reflog delete --rewrite stash@{1}
git reflog delete --rewrite stash@{0}
```

(I put these in reverse order here because every deletion decreases the numbering of the following entries. In practice, don’t bother doing the math mentally, just do `git stash list` after every deletion to get an updated list and pick another remaining broken entry from that.)

Answer (score 3):

all above answers don't work for me, the below command work, it can delete one stash which you want. I hope it will work for you.

```
git stash list

//--- apply target stash
git stash apply refs/stash@{n} 

//---- delete target stash
git stash drop --index n
// or
git stash drop refs/stash@{n}
```

Comment: I had an issue with being unable to pop stash, using refs/stash@{n} instead of stash@{n} helped