# List modified file names in a git stash

Tags: git, git-stash

Can I list the names of the modified files in a stash, without their contents?

While searching, I only found people printing the whole diff, couldn't manage to view the filenames only.

Comment: `git stash show` passes your arguments on to `git diff`, so use `--name-only` as usual.

Comment: @torek convert it to an answer, please! : )

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `show` sub-command, in the end, invokes `git diff` with whatever flags you have set, or `--stat` if you did not set any, so simply `git stash show --name-only`, which runs `git diff --name-only` between the base commit and the work-tree commit.

(See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412685/1256452) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452) for a description of what I have taken to calling a "git stash-bag".  You get a diff between the commit the bag hangs from, and the `w` commit.)

Comment: If you're having the opposite problem, e.g. YADR shows the names only when you run `git stash show`, try `git stash show --patch`.

Comment: git stash  show --name-only stash@{0} for a selected stash

Comment: @RachitaNanda: yes, or in modern Git you can just write the number (`git stash show <flags> 2` for stash stack entry #2 for instance). Note that I recommend avoiding `git stash` as much as possible; if you have a stack of five stashes, you have five stashes too many. :-)