# Generating patch file from an old stash

Tags: git

I wish to create a `.patch` file based on the diff of an old stash that I can view with `git stash show -p stash@{2}`

I tried this, but no luck:

```
git format-patch stash@{2} --stdout > file.patch
```

I assumed it would work like a normal commit? Apologies for being most likely uber-thick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The output of `git stash show -p` is itself a valid patch.  You can use it directly:

```
git stash show -p stash@{2} > file.patch
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [the `git format-patch` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html), if you specify a single commit,<sup>1</sup> then:

> 1. A single commit, *`since`*, specifies that the commits leading to the tip of the current branch that are not in the history that leads to the *`since`* to be output.

Thus, `format-patch` tries to find "commits leading to the tip of the current branch" (`HEAD`) that are neither themselves `stash@{2}` nor ancestors of `stash@{2}`.  It's hard to say precisely which commits these will be without knowing the actual commit graph, but if the graph looks something like this:

```
... - o - o - * - *   <-- HEAD=branch
          |\
          i-w   <-- stash@{2}
```

then `format-patch` would make a patch containing the two commits marked `*`: they are the only ancestors of `HEAD` that are not removed by starting at the `w` commit and working backwards.

If the graph looks more like this:

```
              *   <-- HEAD=branch
            /
... - o - o - o - o   <-- anotherbranch
              |\
              i-w   <-- stash@{2}
```

then once again you would get the commit marked `*` (one commit this time, just to be a bit different).

(In fact, you get precisely the same commits as for `stash@{2}..HEAD`, since this [`gitrevisions` syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) means what's in item 1 of the `format-patch` documentation).

One solution is to proceed to item 2 in the `format-patch` documentation:

> 2. Generic *revision range* expression (see "SPECIFYING REVISIONS" section in gitrevisions(7)) means the commits in the specified range.

Here you need only specify the commits from "just before the `w` commit in the stash-bag" to "the `w` commit itself", which is simply `stash@{2}^..stash@{2}`:

```
git format-patch [additional options like --stdout here] stash@{2}^..stash@{2}
```

Since this is a single commit, the only difference between this and just using `git show` (as [John Zwinck suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26117064/1256452)) is the precise formatting of the patch (`format-patch` makes mailbox style patches by default).

---

Alternatively, you can *always* turn a stash into a "real branch" using `git stash branch`.  This turns the index commit `i` of the stash into a real commit if needed, and restores the work directory state (and the untracked or all-files state as well, if one of those was included in the stash) after creating a new branch starting at the parent commit, i.e., the one the stash-bag is attached to.  Commit the resulting work-tree and you have an ordinary branch, which you can manipulate with all the ordinary branch operations (including `format-patch`).

---

<sup>1</sup>See [some of my other descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412685/1256452) [about git "stash bags"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452) to see that a stash is a small clump of commits, but note that the name `stash@{2}` identifies a single commit, specifically the work-tree commit in the "stash bag".

Comment: Thanks for the info, but John actually answered the question directly so his is the one I've accepted! Cheers

Comment: You might consider replicating the commands you need and explain why you might want a mailbox patch (or where it goes) to replicate John's answer - using your answer produces two blank patch files whereas @john-zwinck 's "just works".