# How do I properly git stash/pop in pre-commit hooks to get a clean working tree for tests?

Tags: git, githooks, git-stash

I'm trying to do a pre-commit hook with a bare run of unit tests and I want to make sure my working directory is clean.  Compiling takes a long time so I want to take advantage of reusing compiled binaries whenever possible.  My script follows examples I've seen online:

```
# Stash changes
git stash -q --keep-index

# Run tests
...

# Restore changes
git stash pop -q
```

This causes problems though.  Here's the repro:

1. Add `// Step 1` to `a.java`
2. `git add .`
3. Add `// Step 2` to `a.java`
4. `git commit`

   1. `git stash -q --keep-index` # Stash changes
   2. Run tests
   3. `git stash pop -q` # Restore changes

At this point I hit the problem.  The `git stash pop -q` apparently has a conflict and in `a.java` I have

```
// Step 1
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
=======
// Step 2
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

Is there a way to get this to pop cleanly?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is—but let's get there in a slightly roundabout fashion.  (Also, see warning below: there's a bug in the stash code which I thought was very rare, but apparently more people are running into.  New warning, added in Dec 2021: `git stash` has been rewritten in C and has a whole new crop of bugs.  I used to suggest mildly that `git stash` be avoided; now I urge *everyone* to **avoid it if at all possible**.)

`git stash push` (the default action for `git stash`; note that this was spelled `git stash save` in 2015, when I wrote the first version of this answer) makes a commit that has at least two parents (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412685/1256452) to a more basic question about stashes).  The `stash` commit is the work-tree state, and the second parent commit `stash^2` is the index-state at the time of the stash.

After the stash is made (and assuming no `-p` option), the script—`git stash` is a shell script—uses `git reset --hard` to clean out the changes.

When you use `--keep-index`, the script does not change the saved stash in any way.  Instead, after the `git reset --hard` operation, the script uses an extra `git read-tree --reset -u` to wipe out the work-directory changes, replacing them with the "index" part of the stash.

In other words, it's almost like doing:

```
git reset --hard stash^2
```

except that `git reset` would also move the branch—not at all what you want, hence the `read-tree` method instead.

This is where your code comes back in.  You now `# Run tests` on the contents of the index commit.

Assuming all goes well, I presume you want to get the index back into the state it had when you did the `git stash`, and get the work-tree back into its state as well.

With `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`, the way to do that is to use `--index` (not `--keep-index`, that's just for stash-creation time, to tell the stash script "whack on the work directory").

Just using `--index` will still fail though, because `--keep-index` re-applied the index changes to the work directory.  So you must first get rid of all of those changes ... and to do that, you simply need to (re)run `git reset --hard`, just like the stash script itself did earlier.  (Probably you also want `-q`.)

So, this gives as the last `# Restore changes` step:

```
# Restore changes
git reset --hard -q
git stash pop --index -q
```

(I'd separate them out as:

```
git stash apply --index -q && git stash drop -q
```

myself, just for clarity, but the `pop` will do the same thing).

---

As noted in a comment below, the final `git stash pop --index -q` complains a bit (or, worse, restores an *old* stash) if the initial `git stash push` step finds no changes to save.  You should therefore protect the "restore" step with a test to see if the "save" step actually stashed anything.

The initial `git stash --keep-index -q` simply exits quietly (with status 0) when it does nothing, so we need to handle two cases: no stash exists either before or after the save; and, some stash existed before the save, and the save did nothing so the old existing stash is still the top of the stash stack.

I think the simplest method is to use `git rev-parse` to find out what `refs/stash` names, if anything.  So we should have the script read something more like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
# script to run tests on what is to be committed

# First, stash index and work dir, keeping only the
# to-be-committed changes in the working directory.
old_stash=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)
git stash push -q --keep-index
new_stash=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)

# If there were no changes (e.g., `--amend` or `--allow-empty`)
# then nothing was stashed, and we should skip everything,
# including the tests themselves.  (Presumably the tests passed
# on the previous commit, so there is no need to re-run them.)
if [ "$old_stash" = "$new_stash" ]; then
    echo "pre-commit script: no changes to test"
    sleep 1 # XXX hack, editor may erase message
    exit 0
fi

# Run tests
status=...

# Restore changes
git reset --hard -q && git stash apply --index -q && git stash drop -q

# Exit with status from test-run: nonzero prevents commit
exit $status
```

---

### warning: small bug in git stash

(Note: I believe this bug was fixed in the conversion to C.  Instead, there are numerous *other* bugs now.  They will no doubt eventually be fixed, but depending on which version of Git you are using, `git stash` may have various bugs of varying seriousness.)

There's a minor bug in the way `git stash` writes its ["stash bag"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20586009/1256452).  The index-state stash is correct, but suppose you do something like this:

```
cp foo.txt /tmp/save                    # save original version
sed -i '' -e '1s/^/inserted/' foo.txt   # insert a change
git add foo.txt                         # record it in the index
cp /tmp/save foo.txt                    # then undo the change
```

When you run `git stash push` after this, the index-commit (`refs/stash^2`) has the inserted text in `foo.txt`.  The work-tree commit (`refs/stash`) *should* have the version of `foo.txt` without the extra inserted stuff.  If you look at it, though, you'll see it has the wrong (index-modified) version.

The script above uses `--keep-index` to get the working tree set up as the index was, which is all perfectly fine and does the right thing for running the tests.  After running the tests, it uses `git reset --hard` to go back to the `HEAD` commit state (which is still perfectly fine) ... and then it uses `git stash apply --index` to restore the index (which works) and the work directory.

This is where it goes wrong.  The index is (correctly) restored from the stash index commit, but the work-directory is restored from the stash work-directory commit.  This work-directory commit has the version of `foo.txt` that's in the index.  In other words, that last step—`cp /tmp/save foo.txt`—that undid the change, has been un-un-done!

(The bug in the `stash` script occurs because the script compares the work-tree state against the `HEAD` commit in order to compute the set of files to record in the special temporary index before making the special work-dir commit part of the stash-bag.  Since `foo.txt` is unchanged with respect to `HEAD`, it fails to `git add` it to the special temporary index.  The special work-tree commit is then made with the index-commit's version of `foo.txt`.  The fix is very simple but no one has put it into official git [yet?].

Not that I want to encourage people to modify their versions of git, but [here's the fix](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-stash-doesn-t-always-save-work-dir-as-is-bug-tp7595679.html).)

Comment: Your answer makes me wish there was a nice infographic/flowchart for git so that I could understand what's actually going on.  Still reading and trying to grok.

Comment: There are some, but none are complete because it's so ridiculously complicated.  As an alternative to using `git stash` though, you could consider creating two commits of your own, on a branch of your own creation, or even on the current branch.  (It will work out the same in the end no matter which way you go. :-) )

Comment: That's what I feel like.  I'd love to take a whack at it myself, but like you said: so ridiculously complicated.  The multiple commit thing is a no-go for me though.  In our environment each commit corresponds to a separately code-reviewed change.  Multiple changes would lead to an explosion of code reviews, particularly in a hook.  In general we have to constantly amend our last change whenever you want to review a minor edit to a change.

Comment: Works like charm! Thks. I have one problem, though. If you commit with `--amend` to fix the commit message (no files changed or modified or anything), you get some errors, I think with `pop`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Nico: when you `git commit --amend` you are actually adding a new, different commit to the commit-graph.  The ["stash bag"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20586009/1256452) is still hung off the old commit.  If the trees of the old and new commits match, the stash should apply cleanly, even with `--index`.  I'd have to see the errors to say more, but you can compare the old and new commit trees with `git diff`.  Just give it both commit specifiers (e.g., `HEAD` and `stash^` before attempting the `git stash apply`).

Comment: @torek follow this steps: Make a change on a file, add and commit. `git status` shows "nothing to commit, working dir is clean". Now run `git commit --amend -m "new commit msg"`. When the `pre-commit` hook runs, it fails with "No stash found."

Comment: @Nico: Ah, I see now.  The problem is that when this whole thing is dumped into a pre-commit hook, the initial `git stash save -q --keep-index` is just an expensive no-op as `git stash save` decides there are no local changes to save (run it without -q to see the message).  One must detect this case and avoid attempting to restore the non-existent saved stash.  I'll add a bit of code to the answer.

Comment: @torek Awesome, works great. Thanks and thanks for the example. I found it very hard to find good and complete examples of pre-commit hooks for git.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in this scenario: 1) edit line 5 in file x.txt 2) add this change to commit, 3) edit line 5 in file x.txt again, 4) at this point developer wants to commit. When I run this script then the end state is - I have lost the unstaged change to line 5. :(

Comment: @zilupe: there's a long standing bug in `git stash` that you could be hitting here.  Are you changing line 5 back to the way it was before `git add`ing?  If so, you're hitting the bug.  I posted a fix to the mailing list but it was apparently ignored...

Comment: @torek yes, you are absolutely right! That explains it. Thank you.

Comment: Great solution and helped me a lot in [the other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536034/modifying-working-directory-and-staging-area-temporarily-in-git-pre-commit-hook). It's a bit maddening that there's no way to get `git stash` to return a different exit code if it actually created a new stash (along the lines`git diff --exit-code`)... that would simplify the `rev-parse` ugliness.

Comment: If the purpose of `git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash` is to check whether or not anything was stashed, what’s wrong with using `git stash list | wc -l`? The latter is much easier for me to wrap my tiny brain around.

Comment: @JezenThomas: That should work too: if the count goes up, you got a new stash.  However, that's substantially more processes and code to run (`git rev-parse` is one binary doing, in this case, just a few simple things; `git stash list` is a script that runs half a gazillion sub-commands—well, ok, probably just 3 or 4 here :-)—and then `wc -l` has to read and count all the output lines written over the pipe).

Comment: Had to downvote, as `git stash save` is deprecated in favor of `git stash push`. I don't know what from this whole thread is still relevant.

Comment: @DevinRhode: `git stash push` did not even *exist* when I wrote the answer above. Also, `git stash` has been rewritten in C, and a whole new crop of bugs added: now you *really* should avoid `git stash`.

Comment: Yeah I've found new/untracked files are particularly weird...

Comment: FYI @torek - I search official git release notes for `stash` and have uploaded results here - https://gist.github.com/devinrhode2/1284e8ef0052a5f086b2055e72637d8a - Maybe the new C bugs are getting fixed, idk. Also, I removed my downvote :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answer of @torek I was able to put together a script that also deals with untracked files. (Note: I don't want to use `git stash -u` due to a unwanted behaviour of [git stash -u](http://blog.icefusion.co.uk/git-stash-can-delete-ignored-files-git-stash-u/))

The mentioned `git stash` bug remains unchanged and I am not yet sure, whether this method might run into issues when a .gitignore is among the changed files. (same applies to @torek's answer)

```
#! /bin/sh
# script to run tests on what is to be committed
# Based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/20480591/1606867

# Remember old stash
old_stash=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)

# First, stash index and work dir, keeping only the
# to-be-committed changes in the working directory.
git stash save -q --keep-index
changes_stash=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)
if [ "$old_stash" = "$changes_stash" ]
then
    echo "pre-commit script: no changes to test"
    sleep 1 # XXX hack, editor may erase message
    exit 0
fi

#now let's stash the staged changes
git stash save -q
staged_stash=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)
if [ "$changes_stash" = "$staged_stash" ]
then
    echo "pre-commit script: no staged changes to test"
    # re-apply changes_stash
    git reset --hard -q && git stash pop --index -q
    sleep 1 # XXX hack, editor may erase message
    exit 0
fi

# Add all untracked files and stash those as well
# We don't want to use -u due to
# http://blog.icefusion.co.uk/git-stash-can-delete-ignored-files-git-stash-u/
git add .
git stash save -q
untracked_stash=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)

#Re-apply the staged changes
if [ "$staged_stash" = "$untracked_stash" ]
then
    git reset --hard -q && git stash apply --index -q stash@{0}
else
    git reset --hard -q && git stash apply --index -q stash@{1}
fi

# Run tests
status=...

# Restore changes

# Restore untracked if any
if [ "$staged_stash" != "$untracked_stash" ]
then
    git reset --hard -q && git stash pop --index -q
    git reset HEAD -- . -q
fi

# Restore staged changes
git reset --hard -q && git stash pop --index -q

# Restore unstaged changes
git reset --hard -q && git stash pop --index -q

# Exit with status from test-run: nonzero prevents commit
exit $status
```

Comment: I created a more sophisticated hook framework using this script as a base for anyone who's interested: https://github.com/schamp/capn-hook

Comment: > _I am recommending capn-hook be deprecated, since the introduction of the most excellent [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/). It does everything capn-hook was meant to do, only better. Go there instead, but I will keep this around for historical purposes._

Comment: I'm looking through git stash release notes... https://gist.github.com/devinrhode2/1284e8ef0052a5f086b2055e72637d8a
I'm thinking this has probably been fixed in the last ~7 years, so I'm going to try and do what I want from scratch reading the docs, and then post my answer back here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that most answers here, at this time, are at least 5 years old. `git stash` has been re-written in C, there were some new bugs, and I don't really know how reliable it is.

I've used this a few times and it seems to be working - I wrote it from scratch, just using the docs as a guide. Has not been battle tested.

```sh
# We stash and un-stash changes ourselves.
#  - If any pre-commit/lint-staged checks fail, any auto-fixes will be lost.

# Create stash
#   index is the "staging area", so --keep-index means that anything you have already staged will be un-touched.
# NOTE: we always create a stash - possibly even a totally empty one.
git stash --keep-index --include-untracked --message="pre-commit auto-stash"
uncoloredStashedStat=$(git stash show --include-untracked stash@{0})
[[ $uncoloredStashedStat ]] && {
  echo "Stashed:"
  git diff --stat --staged stash@{0}
}

lintStagedStatus='failed'

yarn lint-staged --no-stash --concurrent $pre_commit_concurrency --shell "/bin/bash"  && {
  lintStagedStatus='passed'
}

outputSuppressed=$(git add --intent-to-add "**/*.snap")
diff=$(git diff)
[[ $diff ]] && {
  echo "staging modifications from pre-commit scripts:"
  git diff
  git add .
}

# Pop stash
#   We always create a stash - so we will always pop it.
#   Popped stash should generally not cause merge conflicts,
#   if your editor is formatting+autofixing code on save.
[[ $uncoloredStashedStat ]] && echo "restoring stash..."
git stash pop

if test "$lintStagedStatus" != 'passed'; then
  exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I got some good help from this, but what does this line do: `outputSuppressed=$(git add --intent-to-add "**/*.snap")`?

Comment: haha, I BARELY know bash, just enough to accidentally "take down prod" if you will.

Comment: The `git add` command here is wrapped in `outputSuppressed=$(` so that the output of this command does not appear to users of this script (i.e. other developers)

Answer (score 0):

based off torek's answer I came up with a method to ensure the right behavior of stashing changes **without** using ***git rev-parse***, instead I used ***git stash create*** and ***git stash store*** (although using *git stash store* is not strictly necessary) Note due to the environment I am working in my script is written in php instead of bash

```
#!/php/php
<?php
$files = array();
$stash = array();
exec('git stash create -q', $stash);
$do_stash = !(empty($stash) || empty($stash[0]));
if($do_stash) {
    exec('git stash store '.$stash[0]); //store the stash (does not tree state like git stash save does)
    exec('git stash show -p | git apply --reverse'); //remove working tree changes
    exec('git diff --cached | git apply'); //re-add indexed (ready to commit) changes to working tree
}
//exec('git stash save -q --keep-index', $stash);
exec('git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD', $files );

// dont redirect stderr to stdin, we will get the errors twice, redirect it to dev/null
if ( PHP_OS == 'WINNT' )
  $redirect = ' 2> NUL';
else
  $redirect = ' 2> /dev/null';
$exitcode = 0;

foreach( $files as $file ) {

  if ( !preg_match('/\.php$/i', $file ) )
    continue;

  exec('php -l ' . escapeshellarg( $file ) . $redirect, $output, $return );
  if ( !$return ) // php -l gives a 0 error code if everything went well
    continue;

  $exitcode = 1; // abort the commit
  array_shift( $output ); // first line is always blank
  array_pop( $output ); // the last line is always "Errors parsing httpdocs/test.php"

  echo implode("\n", $output ), "\n"; // an extra newline to make it look good
}
if($do_stash) {
    exec('git reset --hard -q');
    exec('git stash apply --index -q');
    exec('git stash drop -q');
}
exit( $exitcode );

?>
```

php script adapted from here http://blog.dotsamazing.com/2010/04/ask-git-to-check-if-your-codes-are-error-free/