# Git hooks - update file md5sum automatically upon commit

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

One of the scripts in my git repository is distributed to many users. When they run this script I would it to look into my repository and see if any change is made to this script and if so suggest the users to update the script from the repository. The users know nothing about git and wish to understand as little as possible in the system implementation.

I would like to automatically update a this script's md5sum every time I commit it, without the need to bother and do it manually. Here is the pre-commit hook I wrote

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "# "  > test.txt.tmp
linesNumber=`wc -l test.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
tail -n $(($linesNumber - 1)) test.txt | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >> test.txt.tmp
tail -n $(($linesNumber - 1)) test.txt >> test.txt.tmp
mv test.txt.tmp test.txt
#git push
#git commit --no-verify --message "update file md5sum"
```

The md5sum works fine, the problem is that after the commit my script is again shows as modified. I tried to commit my changes without running the pre-commit hook (--no-verify) but git says I can't commit because my branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit, I tried to push my changes before committing the md5sum but it never finished the operation.

What is the right way to achieve this type of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pre-commit hook does not `git add` the updated `test.txt` file.

Note that the version of the file in the working directory is not necessarily the version that would be committed:

```
echo foo > test.txt
git add test.txt
echo bar > test.txt
git commit -m 'this commit has "foo" in test.txt'
```

To see, in a pre-commit hook, the version of the file in the index—i.e., what will be committed if the pre-commit hook allows the commit to proceed, without doing any `git add` step—you can use `git show :0:test.txt`.  The magic `:0:` prefix is [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) syntax for "version staged for commit".  (You can abbreviate this further as just `:test.txt`, although I find the `:0:` a bit more obvious as a revspec; I've seen real files really named `:README` for instance. :-) )  Note that this bypasses any smudge filter(s) though.

(Hooks that want to test the entire current index contents, but preserve working directory state as well, can use `git stash save --keep-index`.  See [How do I properly git stash/pop in pre-commit hooks to get a clean working tree for tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20480591/1256452) for advice, and a caveat, on doing this.)

In my current version of git (1.8.5.4), if I modify a file and `git add` the result in a pre-commit hook, the contents I `add`ed are what goes into the commit.  (I do have some vague recollection of an earlier version of git saving the index before the pre-commit hook runs, so that changes made to the index did not make it into the commit, but I might just be mis-remembering.)

Aside: It's generally not a great idea to modify the commit-contents in a pre-commit hook.  They're really just meant to *verify* that the commit is ready to go.  But if you're determined to modify the contents, `git add` (or `git update-index` but add is much simpler) will do it.

Comment: I updated my git version to 1.9 and I added `git add test.txt` before the `git commit` command. Now I'm getting this error message
"error: Ref refs/heads/master is at 710174cafabb7baf34ddeae21f16df178816cefe but expected ee25c68f58161015f9654559a155da2851a059bd"

Comment: Interesting.  Is there now a `git commit` *inside* the pre-commit hook?  This could confuse the later `git commit` that is going to happen when the pre-commit hook exits.

Comment: But I use `git commit --no-verify`, the pre-commit hook shouldn't be called. Perhaps totally different idea? Suppose you wanted to put some sort of identifier in some file every time you commit a change to this file, how would you do it?

Comment: Yes, with `--no-verify` the *inner* commit (run by your hook) skips the hook.  Then the *outer* commit (the one that is running your hook) goes to make a new commit, but "hey wait a minute before I called the pre-commit hook I had refs/heads/master set this way, now it's different!"  For me, if I were doing this, I would just make the hook *check* that the file has the desired value, not attempt to put a *new* value in.  Then I might use a git alias (e.g., `git ci` aliased to run a script) to update the file before running `git commit`.