# Checking comments in code for messages before committing with Git

Tags: linux, macos, git, git-commit, pre-commit

If often find myself writing out helpful messages in my code when developing locally. See this code snippet as a simple example:

```
# Public API
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    # REMOVE THE FIRST LINE WHEN DONE TESTING
    get :delivery_report, to: 'delivery_report#index'
    post :delivery_report, to: 'delivery_report#index'
  end
end
```

The point here is that when I am done and I feel like I can finally commit my work I need to remember that I have to remove the line `get :delivery_report, to: 'delivery_report#index'`

Is it somehow possible to tell git that before accepting a commit or maybe before staging it, it should warn me about a line in my code that has some content? In this case that would be my comment or any other pre-defined line.

Answer (score 0):

Git supports a "pre-commit hook", in which you can test what the user has proposed committing, and force the commit to fail if some condition(s) apply.

See [git pre-commit hook code formatting with partial commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22858850/1256452) and [How do I properly git stash/pop in pre-commit hooks to get a clean working tree for tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20479794/1256452)