# Is it possible to disable a "dangerous" command line option in git?

Tags: git, git-config

By habit, I'll often work on a change in my repo, and add/commit it in one shot using `git commit -am 'my commit message'`

There are times when I only want to add a few of the modified files, so I'll issue preparatory `git add` commands to meticulously set-up my staging area, and separate the ready-to-commit changes from the half-baked changes.

Then, I'll fat-finger the whole thing by issuing the same `git commit -am '...'` command as I usually do.

Would there be a way for me to disable the `git commit -a` option, and/or issue a warning when I use the `-a` switch? I want to train myself out of this sketchy habit...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a wrapper script named `git` that will catch bad commands and forward good ones on to the real `git`. Put it earlier in your `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ARG in "${@}"; do
    if [ "${ARG}" = "-am" ]; then
        echo "Hey! Don’t do that!" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

exec /usr/bin/git "${@}"
```

Almost all git commands will work just fine:

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 1183, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (728/728), done.
remote: Total 1183 (delta 771), reused 632 (delta 455)
Receiving objects: 100% (1183/1183), 1.12 MiB | 1.46 MiB/s, done.
...
```

But the ones you don’t want to work won’t:

```
$ git commit -am "foo"
Hey! Don’t do that!
```

Comment: This would not work properly if the user calls `git commit -am"blah blah"`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a [`git config` setting](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) which would prevent/disallow the `--all/-a` option of a [`git commit`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit).

You could consider though a:

- [`pre-commit` hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks) (here a [`hooks--pre-commit.sample`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample)):

  ```
  git stash save -q --keep-index "possible commit am"
  ```

(`-q` for 'quiet')

That would remove from the working tree any of your modification (except the ones already added to the index)

- `post-commit` hook

  ```
  if [[ "$(git stash list|| grep "stash@{0}" | grep "possible commit am")" != "" ]]; then
    git stash pop -q
  fi
  ```

That should allow you to type a `git commit -[a]m "a commit message"` without committing everything.
And if you want to skip those hooks for one commit:

```
git commit --no-verify -m "a commit message"
```

Comment: Note to self: other great tips around pre-commit hook: http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/. Also interesting https://github.com/jish/pre-commit, https://gist.github.com/Simbul/1781656

Comment: Also: (1) beware of bug in `git stash` (noted in first comment on linked page); (2) note that if there are no changes to stash, `git stash -q --keep-index` is a no-op, in which case you should *not* run `git stash pop -q` as there was no stash pushed.  Solving the second one is tricky if you use two separate hooks.

Comment: @torek regarding the bug, I believe you explain it at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20480591/6309. And you should be able to check if git stash list includes a stash made after a possible `commit -am`: I have added a crude test in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I just figured there should be a note here as well, on that stash bug.  Probably should have looked up my earlier answer myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to **fish shell**, so it won't be useful to everyone... but it might be to some!

```
function git
  if string match 'commit' $argv[1] > /dev/null
    set has_am 0

    for arg in $argv
      if string match -r -- '^-am.*' $arg > /dev/null
        set has_am 1
      end
    end

    if test $has_am -eq 1
      echo -e "Commit All detected.\nDon't do this!"
    else
      command git $argv
    end
  else
    command git $argv
  end
end
```