# pre-receive hook unable to read the committed file to push into remote master

Tags: git, bash, github, sed

i tried the following in pre-receive file in my server but my pre-commit on my local git repository works without any issues

```
#!/bin/bash 
git rev-parse -q --verify HEAD && sed -n -e '/^<<\+ /q1' -n -e '/^>>\+ /q1' $(git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD $(git write-tree)) || { echo "Git conflict (<<<<) or (>>>>) exists in one of the committed files."; exit 1; }
```

but get the error like `remote: sed: can't read /App/abc/TestFile.java:No such file or directory`

please help me in resolving it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a mess.

Let's just take this part first, from your pre-commit hook:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD $(git write-tree)
```

The inner `git write-tree` writes the index to a tree and returns its hash value.  For the sake of example let's say it's `01234567`.

You then run `git diff` with three commit-or-tree-ish arguments (all three arguments can be resolved to a tree identifier, which is what git cares about here):

```
HEAD^ HEAD 01234567
```

This invokes an undocumented bit of behavior in git diff: it produces a "combined diff".  The inputs to the combined diff are considered to be several parents (all but the first argument) and one child (the first argument), so this treats the tree you just wrote, and the `HEAD` commit in the repository, as the two parent commits, with `HEAD^` as the child commit.

The [`git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_diff_format_for_merges) notes that a combined diff "lists only files which were modified from all parents."  In this case, again, the two "parents" are the proposed new commit's tree (from `git write-tree`) and the `HEAD` commit (that which is currently at the tip of the current branch).  Where *both* of those differ from `HEAD^` (the first parent of the tip of the current branch), git will show you a diff.  This is not what you want!  (Since you also specified `--name-only`, git will show you just the file names, not the actual diff.)

You then take those names and look in those files for git's "conflict markers" (the `<<<` and `>>>` marks around conflicting regions).  This part is not as wrong (but is still slightly broken), but at this point things are already wrong because you may be looking at the wrong files.

Consider, for instance, the case where commit `HEAD^` lacks file `f2`, commit `HEAD` adds file `f2`, and the current index modifies file `f3` but has a git conflict in it:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/repo; cd /tmp/repo; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/repo/.git/
$ echo ordinary file > f1; git add f1
$ echo another ordinary file > f3
$ git add f1 f3; git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) f181096] initial
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 f1
 create mode 100644 f3
$ echo new file f2 > f2; git add f2
$ git commit -m 'add f2'
[master c06f8d1] add f2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 f2
$ (echo '<<< conflict'; echo '==='; echo '>>> end conflict') > f3
$ git add f3 # but we never resolved our (fake) conflict
$ git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD $(git write-tree)
f2
```

There's the problem: the combined diff did not look at `f3` as it is not modified in both "parents" vs the "child" (of course these "parent"/"child" relationships are nonsensical anyway).  Without `--name-only` we see the combined diff output:

```
$ git diff HEAD^ HEAD $(git write-tree)
diff --cc f2
index 9d57e62,9d57e62..0000000
deleted file mode 100644,100644
--- a/f2
+++ /dev/null
@@@ -1,1 -1,1 +1,0 @@@
--new file f2
```

If you want to check whether your proposed new commit's tree has some files with conflict markers, you need to examine the proposed "blobs", rather than the current working tree.  (This is because you can `git add` a file, then modify it further; or `git add -p` to interactively select parts to add and parts to defer adding.  Hence, the contents of the index may not match the working directory.)  There are a number of ways to do this; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20479794/1256452) and its answer for one method, and below (using `git show` with a revision-and-path) for another.  The code you have now will work for *some* cases, but definitely not all.

---

With that out of the way, I see that [Ikke has already answered the other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24362165/1256452), which is that a bare repository—the usual target for `git push` operations, and the place where you would run a pre-receive hook—has no work tree, so you can't look at files in that work tree.  Pre-receive hooks are generally more difficult to write as you must handle many cases:

- multiple commits
- references that are not branches (tags)
- objects that are not commits (annotated tags)
- branch creations and deletions as well as updates

When a branch (a reference of the form `refs/heads/name`) is proposed to be updated, the pre-receive hook gets its current SHA-1 and a proposed new SHA-1.  You can then use `git rev-list` to find the sequence of objects that will be on (or no longer on) the branch if you allow the update.  For each such object, if it's a commit, you would examine the tree attached to that commit, to see if all the blobs (files) in that tree pass inspection.

**Please note that `pre-receive` and `update` hooks are very different from other git "pre" hooks:** in both cases, the proposed new commits and/or annotated-tags are actually already in the repository (although they may be stripped out again if your hook rejects them), and you should generally refer to these proposed git objects by object-ID (SHA-1).  (It's OK to walk the commit tree; in fact, you *must* do this in many cases.)  The point here is that what is correct for a pre-commit hook is almost guaranteed to be wrong for a pre-receive hook, and vice versa.

A rough outline of this process might be:

```
NULL_SHA1=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

check_revs()
{
    local range branch rev rtype path

    range=$1
    branch=$2
    git rev-list $range |
    while read rev; do
        rtype=$(git cat-file -t $rev)
        case $rtype in
        commit) ;;
        *) continue;; # skip annotated tags
        esac
        git diff --name-only ${rev}^ $rev |
        while read path; do
            if git show ${rev}:$path | grep forbidden-item; then
                echo "error: branch ${branch}: ${rev}:$path contains forbidden-item" 1>&2
                exit 1
            fi
        done
    done
}

check_branch()
{
    local old new branch

    old=$1
    new=$2
    branch=$3

    if [ $old = $NULL_SHA1 -o $new = $NULL_SHA1 ]; then
        # branch will be created or deleted, not updated
        # do whatever is appropriate here
    else
        # branch will be updated, if we allow it
        check_revs $old..$new $branch
    fi
}

while read oldsha newsha fullref; do
case "$fullref" in
refs/heads/*) check_branch $oldsha $newsha ${fullref#refs/heads/};;
# add cases for refs/tags/* if desired, etc
*) ;;
esac

exit 0 # if we got this far it must be OK to do it
```

(Note that this is entirely untested.  I expect it has a bug in the "file deleted" case, where there is nothing to `git show` in the new revision.  Also, it's not necessarily a good idea to check for `<<<` and the like though.  What happens if there's a text file illustrating how git conflicts look?  You can choose the kind of inspection to do based on the file name, perhaps, but even then, some files might legitimately contain what look like, but are not actually, git conflict markers.  If you choose to do this, make sure you allow some way around it if there is a case when it should be allowed.)

Comment: git diff -p -M --cached HEAD -- in pre-receive file redirecting the output to a file returns a 269MB file. When pushing the committed changes to master, i get "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly". I added git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000 in my git client, but still i get the same error

Comment: `--cached` and `HEAD` in a pre-receive file makes no sense: the commits are already in the repository, there's no index involved, and you're just telling git yea/nay on whether the label-change is allowed.  You need to compare two *specific* revs (SHA-1s or modifications thereof), not use names like `HEAD`.  I do see a missing `$` in front of a `rev` above; will edit to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that sed tries to read the file from the filesystem, but bare repositories don't have a working tree.

`git write-tree` creates a new tree object, it doesn't check out the files, so it isn't suited for what you want.

Also you are only checking the differences of the last commit, while someone can push many commits. The [pre-receive](http://jk.gs/githooks.html) hook provides information on the commits being pushed on `stdin` (see the man page for the format).

You have to iterate each of line and use that to create a diff that you can feed into `sed`

Answer (score 0):

`git diff "$old_commit"..."$latest_commit"` where old_commit and latest_commit are the default inputs to pre-receive. It displays the diffs between the oldest & the latest commits.