# git: how to grep received files in pre-receive hook

Tags: git

I created the following pre-push script in my local repository `.git/hooks/` to disallow pushing files with unresolved git conflicts to server:

```
#!/bin/bash
top_dir=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
conflicts=$(grep -r -n -s --include=\*.{pm,pl,mc,mi,js,css} "<<<<<<< HEAD" "$top_dir")

if [ "$conflicts" = "" ]; then
    exit 0
else
    printf "Unresolved git conflict found, commit rejected.\n\n"
    echo "$conflicts"
    exit 1
fi
```

It works. But how can we reject all the commits with unresolved conflicts on server side `pre-receive`? Here I know `top_dir` - the dir, where to grep. But on server there are no saved files saved. I need to grep among the files that the client sends me.

How to do it?

Comment: Why did you ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63781852/git-how-to-grep-received-files-in-pre-receive-hook) twice?

Comment: @dan1st (I think this was the first one) --- (I would also assume that someone else is using their account)

Comment: According to the timestamp, this is the second one. According to the ids, this is the first one

Comment: Oh, he removed it.

Comment: Pushed references are sent to `stdin` on the pre-receive hook.

Answer (score 1):

As [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) documents in "[`pre-receive` hook unable to read the committed file to push into remote `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24363412/6309)":

> Pre-receive hooks are generally more difficult to write as you must handle many cases:
>
> - multiple commits
> - references that are not branches (tags)
> - objects that are not commits (annotated tags)
> - branch creations and deletions as well as updates

That kind of hook [works well for commit messages](https://gist.github.com/jtbonhomme/b88cfc3eda108fae75059ae83129d9cb).
That being said, you can see [an example here](https://gist.github.com/1253485/8bd783cbb38ec3e4f000b33afce6a9d215294f2a), in the nominal case:

```sh
# <oldrev> <newrev> <refname>
while  read oldrev newrev ref ;
do
    list = $ ( git show --pretty = " format: " --name-only $ {newrev}  | grep -e ' .php ' -e ' .phtml ' )
    for  file  in  $ {list} ;  do
        git show $ {newrev} : $ {file}  >  $ TMP_FILE
        OUTPUT = $ ( $ PHPCS_BIN -s --standard = $ PHPCS_CODING_STANDARD  $ TMP_FILE )
        ...
```