# Check if Git has changes programmatically

Tags: git, bash

I want to write a script that allows me to easily change branches keeping my current changes.

```
git stash
go checkout main
git stash pop
```

The problem is if there are currently no changes in the repository. Then `stash pop` will pop off a previous stash. What is the easiest way to check if there are changes to pop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`git stash` is actually a shell (plain sh, not bash) script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-stash.sh), so you can look at what it does to decide whether to make a stash:

```
no_changes () {
        git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD --ignore-submodules -- &&
        git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules &&
        (test -z "$untracked" || test -z "$(untracked_files)")
}

untracked_files () {
        excl_opt=--exclude-standard
        test "$untracked" = "all" && excl_opt=
        git ls-files -o -z $excl_opt
}
```

You can therefore repeat these tests to see if `git stash` will do anything—but that's actually not the best option:

- If `git stash` will do something, first it repeats these tests (and they say there is something to stash), which makes them happen twice in that case.
- If the "right" set of tests ever change, you can mis-predict `git stash`'s action and get into trouble.

Clearly, what you want is to:

1. Run `git stash`, and keep track of whether this did anything.
2. Run `git checkout` on the target branch.
3. If `git stash` stashed something, run `git stash pop` (or perhaps `--apply --keep-index` first, to see if that will do the trick, and resort to applying without `--keep-index` only if required, etc.).

The tricky part is that first step.  It turns out to be easy, you just need to know [how `git stash` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20589663/1256452) in, um, extensive detail, plus some other bits about git's "plumbing commands".  You simply [grab the previous stash stack top if any](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20480591/1256452) before the `git stash save` step, and then grab the new top if any, and compare:

```
old_stash=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)
git stash save [additional arguments here if desired, e.g., -q]
new_stash=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash)
```

If the two refs name different commits, or the old ref is empty and the new is not empty, then `git stash` pushed a new stash on the stack.  If the two refs are both empty, or the two refs name the *same* commit, then `git stash` did nothing:

```
if [ "$old_stash" = "$new_stash" ]; then ...; else ...; fi
```

or, in your case, perhaps something more like:

```
[ "$old_stash" != "$new_stash" ] && git stash pop
```

(these tests make use of the fact that the two empty strings are equal to each other, and not-equal to any non-empty string, in terms of the result from `/bin/[` and the shell's built-in copy thereof).

Answer (score 11):

A easy way to check if there are changed files in the working tree, building on Chris Hayes suggestion, provides a combination of `git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no` (alternativly `-uno`) and `wc -l`.

This will give you the number of changed files.

Here is a script example which should satisfy your needs:

```
changed_files=$(git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | wc -l)
[ $changed_files -gt 0 ] && git stash

< do work > 

[ $changed_files -gt 0 ] && git stash pop
```

For more information on `git status` take a look at the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) ([respectively for `wc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)).

Answer (score 4):

### Using `git status`

`git status --porcelain` is one way, though possibly not the best (i.e. fastest). From the man page:

> --porcelain
>
> Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across Git
>   versions and regardless of user configuration. See below for details.

Usage example:

```
$ git status --porcelain

M tmp/myfile.c

$ git stash
$ git status --porcelain
$
```

There's no output from `git status --porcelain` if there are no changes. One flaw, though - new files will be displayed as `?? newfile.txt`, so you may have to post-process the output to get what you want, since new files will not be stashed:

```
$ git status --porcelain
?? newfile.txt

$ git status --porcelain | grep -v "^\?\?"
$
```

You could do something similar with `git diff`, but since calculating a diff is likely going to take much longer than enumerating the status for any realistic repository, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: (mathspace)chris@cl:~/Projects/mathspace$ git stash
No local changes to save
(mathspace)chris@cl:~/Projects/mathspace$ echo $?
0

Comment: @Casebash Whoops.. I apparently did something weird when testing it because I can't reproduce that behavior. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ChrisHayes To hide untracked files from `git status` output you can use `--untracked-files=no` (or `-uno`), take a look at the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html).