# What plumbing command provides the same functionality as git log --follow?

Tags: git, git-log, git-plumbing, git-rev-list

In an effort to improve stability, I'm currently refactoring all my Git-related shell scripts so that they use only *plumbing* (rather than *porcelain*) commands. In particular, I'm trying to replace calls to `git log` (porcelain) by calls to [`git rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) (plumbing).

However, although `git rev-list` seems to offer much of the functionalities of `git log`, it seems to be missing an option equivalent to `git log`'s `--follow` flag, which tells Git to list commits that affected a path even beyond renames (e.g. `README` -> `README.md`). From the [`git log` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> `--follow`
>
> Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames (works only
>      for a single file).

I've sifted through the [`git rev-list` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list), but I couldn't find any option that does the same as `git log --follow`. What am I missing? Can that be done with `git rev-list`? Or should I use another plumbing command altogether?

Comment: For *simple* renames perhaps you could implement your own version of rename detection with diff-tree?

Comment: @AndrewC Hmmm... I'd rather use something off the shelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `--follow` is actually built (poorly) into `git log` itself.  It turns on the rename-detection machinery, in a special one file only mode, and can then find backwards transitions (new file foo = old file bar).

(It does not find forward transitions, so that if you use `--reverse` and name a path that used to exist, e.g., with the intent of finding what file it became, it simply fails.)

Comment: Hmmm... that's indeed unfortunate. My hopes have been dashed!

Comment: Incidentally that same code path is used in `git blame` which automatically does the equivalent of `--follow`.  So there are *pieces* in there...  I went to look at making it work with `--reverse` a while ago, and it got hairy, though.

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems there would be room for refactoring. Perhaps I'll drop an email on the mailing list. But I'm curious...Running  `git log --author=torek` in the Git-project repository doesn't return any hit. Are you involved under another name?

Comment: No, the only thing I've sent in to the git folks was a fix for "git stash", which they still haven't picked up.

Comment: Good to know that you're a contributor. Maybe I will be too, one day. How long ago did you send them the fix? Maybe you should ping them on the mailing list...

Comment: I have a link in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20480591/1256452 to http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/234153 (it's a "possible" fix because I'm not a heavy stash user and perhaps there's some corner case it doesn't handle...).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll give it a read, when I get the chance.