# Git pre-commit hook to regenerate a file and reject the commit if there are diffs

Tags: python, git, diff, githooks, git-diff

My situation is (roughly analogous to) the following:

We have the directory structure

```
my-repo/
  input.txt
  output-1.bin
  output-2.bin
  output-3.bin
  converter.py
```

For simplicity, let's say that `converter.py` looks like this:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile('input.txt', 'output-1.bin')
copyfile('input.txt', 'output-2.bin')
copyfile('input.txt', 'output-3.bin')
```

We version-control *both* `input.txt` *and* `output-*.bin`. I know, I know, you're going to say that there's no reason to version-control the generated files... but this is non-negotiable in our case. We use the .bin files a lot, they're mission-critical, and we can't risk a subtle bug in `converter.py` screwing them up. Version-controlling both the `converter.py` script *and* the outputs makes sure that the ramifications of any script change are super obvious in the git history.

But this leads us to a problem. We can modify `input.txt` and commit that diff without ever running `converter.py` to update the .bins!

This is a perfect job for a [git pre-commit hook](http://githooks.com).

We can get the list of changed files via `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM`. If that list includes `input.txt` or `converter.py`, then we want to run `converter.py` and then diff the output against the .bin files being committed.

So I have two problems/questions:

- How can I run `converter.py` from within the pre-commit hook, without clobbering whatever uncommitted changes the user might have in his local checkout? This is basically [How do I properly git stash/pop in pre-commit hooks to get a clean working tree for tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479794/how-do-i-properly-git-stash-pop-in-pre-commit-hooks-to-get-a-clean-working-tree)
- How can I then, *after* running `converter.py`, ask git "Are there now any uncommitted diffs in the working tree?" I mean I hope the answer is simply `git diff`, but I'm unsure what exactly `git diff` means when executed from *inside a pre-commit hook*.

The reason this problem is non-trivial is that `converter.py` mutates the state of the working tree, instead of just spitting its output to stdout. Sadly this, too, is a non-negotiable axiom of the problem.

Thoughts? Working code snippets? :)

Comment: Anything that mutates the work tree is problematic because it precludes doing things in parallel.  However, if the user is willing to sit there and wait through the pre-commit hooik while getting nothing else done, see your linked question, and note that `git diff` (compare working tree against index) should indeed do the trick.  There may be some issues with temporary index files (`git commit <specific-file>` and `git commit -a`) here as well, though.

Comment: @torek (1) let's assume `converter.py` is super fast; (2) I'm hoping to hear more about the "there may be some issues" part, because I don't believe I know enough of the corner cases to code the solution myself.

Comment: I'd have to test it out and/or peer at the git source and I don't have time for either, for the next few days at least.  The first thing I'd check is whether `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` is set in the environment during a `git commit -a` or `git commit <specific-file>`, though.

Answer (score 0):

How about copying the script into a temp location, running there and comparing the results with the files in repo?

Comment: This doesn't suggest changing the work tree. Copy all needed files to a temp dir, let it be the whole project, build out files and compare them with those committed. With all those constraints no solution will be much easier.