# Configure git pre-commit hook with pylint and pytest

Tags: git, pytest, githooks, git-bash, pylint

I want to add a pre-commit hook in [git for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) such commit just succeed if all test pass and pylint does not return any warning. I execute those in the command line this way:

```
py.test
pylint mypackage
```

After some research I have come up with the following pre-commit bash file (only for the py.test part):

```
#!/bin/sh
py.test
RESULT=$?
git stash pop -q
[ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1
[ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && exit 1
exit 0
```

It effectively aborts the commit and prints a `No stash found` message at the end. The problem is that when I solve the failing test, the commit does not succeed and it still prints `No stash found`.

How could I solve this, including also pylint checks?

Comment: This looks very odd, because you never do an initial `git stash save`.  See this question and my answer, and beware of the stash bug: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20479794/1256452

Comment: I would suggest you to consider a `pre-push` hook instead... I would be very annoyed if every single commit would run the tests, as I commit often.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira, I also commit frequently, but this can depend on many factors (speed of tests, code size...). Time permitting I prefer early warnings.

Comment: did you run 'git add' again on fixed files ?