# Git stash two branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-stash

**This is the situation:**

1. I made changes on branch A
2. `git stash` on branch A
3. `git checkout B`
4. Made changes on branch B
5. `git stash` on branch B
6. `git checkout A`
7. `git stash pop` on branch A

After step 7 of the list above, the changes I had made on branch A before stashing did not come back but the changes I had made on branch B popped on branch A. I used `cmd z` on branch A and the file went to its previous state, which had the changes I had made. It seemed the HEAD of branch A moved to the HEAD of branch B. The same happened when I `git checkout B` and `git stash pop` on that branch: branch B had all the changes made on branch A but not the changes I had made on branch B. I used `cmd z` again to revert to the branch state I needed.

This caused me a lot of problems for sometime, until I was allowed to commit code again on the project (nobody could commit for a while because there was an automated push to the server on commits and the manager didn't want new code in the server until they ran some tests). How can I pop only the changes made on the branches themselves and not changes made on other branches?

Comment: I don't know of a feature that will tie a stash to a branch. However, a stash entry has a description and by default that description includes the name of the branch it was created from. You can use `git stash list` to see these descriptions. Then e.g. use `git stash pop stash@{1}` to retrieve the second item from the stack.

Comment: Also, automated push after commit seems like a horrible idea! Local commits are THE most important improvement of distributed version control systems over the classical centralized approach. That and backup.

Comment: @Raffael: I will try that command. About the automated push, I think it was temporary for whatever reason it needed to be (in general I agree with you though). I came to the project about 2 weeks ago and I am still getting used to the way things roll.

Comment: Pushing automatically to a backup server would be a feature; what you're working with is plain stupid. +++ I learnt not overusing `git stash` the hard way and I'd recommend you to use it for simple things only. When things get more complicated, I go for temporary branches. Even with properly named stash entries, it's too easy to get lost. +++ There's also `git stash show -p stash@{1}` to view it with details and similar things, but working with branches is simpler.

Comment: I agree, branching is better. Or create a temporary commit at the head of the current branch (I like to name it WIP - work in progress). Whatever suits your scenario better.

Comment: As I said, the project workflow was setup before I came to the project. I did not make the decision. But thanks for the commands.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What `git stash` does is make a commit.<sup>1</sup>

Of course, what `git commit` does is make a commit.  So why do we have `git stash` at all?

A significant difference between these commands is that the commits `git stash` makes are *not on any branches*.  This allows you to `stash` when on one branch, then move to another branch and apply the stash there.  In other words, it lets you move in-progress work.

You can often, but not always, move in-progress work anyway.  See [Git - checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).  When you *can't*, though, you can use `git stash` to deal with this.

On the other hand, if you want to "stash on a branch", as in your case, you are probably better off just making a regular commit, rather than a special stash commit.  Such commits are easier to deal with, and also do not have [a bug that `git stash` has](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20480591/1256452).  You are not likely to hit this bug but "regular commits are simpler and easier to deal with" (commits on branches, vs stashes) is a pretty good reason to avoid `git stash`.

If you prefer to use `git stash` anyway, note that each new stash "pushes" the previous ones up higher in a "stash stack".  The old stash becomes `stash@{1}`, and what was `stash@{1}` becomes `stash@{2}`, and so on.  When you `drop` (discard) or `pop` (attempt to apply, then discard) a stash, the stacked ones above it move back down—so if you were to `git stash drop stash@{3}` when you had `stash@{4}` and `stash@{5}` as well, you would be left with `stash@{3}` and `stash@{4}` now.

You can name any stash, including the most recent one, this way: `stash@{0}` means the same thing as `stash`.  (Git actually implements all this using the *reflog* for `stash`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, it makes at least *two* commits, and sometimes three.  The two commits store the index and work-tree state; the third commit, if present, is from `-u` or `-a` and stores the unstaged (`-u`) or all (`-a`) files.  The work-tree commit is a very odd merge commit, with the index commit as its second parent and the third commit, if present, as its third parent.  The first parent of the work-tree commit, and the sole parent of the index commit, is the commit that was current when you ran `git stash`.

If you draw commit graph fragments—which, any time you are doing anything complicated in Git, is a good idea—the index-and-work-tree commit pair kind of dangles off the original commit, with the `refs/stash` reference pointing to the pair, rather than the branch name.  It looks almost like a small handbag, or a food cache hung from a tree branch to keep it away from bears, or some such, so I like to refer to this as a "stash bag".

Answer (score 3):

Torek (as usual) provides an excellent answer, but I believe the succinct answer here is just to note that the stash contains data as a stack (LIFO). So when you pushed A's work and then B's work, it first pops B then A. So when you went back to A and then did the first pop, you got the saved B work.

Answer (score 1):

Popping a stash re-applies that last stash regardless from which branch you stashed! So, the problem you are posting is that last stash that was created on branch B was re-applied on branch A. Next time, You have to specify which stash you want to pop.

Solution to the given problem:

1. Stash again the current status
2. Pop the stash that is before the last

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

if you type `git stash list` something like this will be displayed based on your given situation

```
stash@{0}: WIP on branch-b
stash@{1}: WIP on branch-a
```

typing `git stash pop` will always get the `stash@{0}` node.

So, if you're in `branch a` and you want to apply your progress in that branch. Basing on the list, you should type:

```
git stash pop stash@{1}
```