# How to programmatically git checkout a file partially

Tags: node.js, git, eslint, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Here is what I'm doing. add a pre-commit hook using npm scripts, [an example repo](https://github.com/Stupidism/react-starter-kit/tree/feature/perfect-lint-staged)

```
"is-commitable": "git status | grep 'Changes to be committed:'",
"stash-pop": "git stash pop >> /dev/null",
"stash-unstaged": "git stash save -k --include-untracked 'unstaged-stash' >> /dev/null",
"check-commitable": "npm run is-commitable || (npm run stash-pop && exit 1)",
"lint-staged": "(eslint . --fix && git add .) || (npm run stash-pop && exit 1)",
"recheck-commitable": "npm run check-commitable",
"stash-linted": "git stash save 'linted-stash' >> /dev/null",
"stash-pop-unstaged": "git stash pop stash@{1}",
"stash-pop-linted": "git read-tree stash && git stash drop",
"clean-lint-staged": "(lint-staged >> /dev/null) || exit 0"
```

### Example

1. have two lines of commited code:

   ```
   line1
   line2
   ```
2. make some changes:

   ```
   * line1-changed
   * line2-changed
   ```
3. partially add one of them:

   ```
   - line1
   + line1-changed
   * line2-changed
   ```
4. run commit and pre-commit hook is triggered

   - stash-unstaged

     ```
     - line1
     + line1-changed
     line2(changed part been stashed in unstaged-stash)
     ```
   - lint-staged

     ```
     - line1
     + line1-fixed
     line2(changed part been stashed in unstaged-stash)
     ```
   - stash-linted

     ```
     line1(changed and fixed part been stashed in linted-stash)
     line2(changed part been stashed in unstaged-stash)
     ```
   - stash-pop-unstaged

     ```
     line1(changed and fixed part been stashed in linted-stash)
     * line2-changed
     ```
   - stash-pop-linted

     ```
     - line1
     + line1-fixed
     * line1-changed
     * line2-changed
     ```
   - clean-lint-staged

     ```
     - line1
     + line1-fixed
     * line2-fixed
     ```

### Problem

The last 2 steps are not perfect.

#### Expected result

I wanted to get

```
- line1
+ line1-fixed
* line2-changed
```

### Actual results

But now I can only get

```
- line1
+ line1-fixed
* line1-changed
* line2-changed
```

or

```
- line1
+ line1-fixed
* line2-fixed
```

### Need help

So can I find a way to programmatically git checkout a file only the staged lines?

Or drop the last step find a way to fix the last 2nd step

Comment: See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/20479794/1256452 - but note that I wrote this before `git stash create` and `git stash store` existed. However, the bug I wrote about is still present. Using `git stash --keep-index` to do all this is generally a bad idea all around.

Comment: I didn't get it. What should I use then? `git stash -q -k`?

Comment: Don't use `git stash` at all. Just commit things: use ordinary commits. If you want to test what *will be* committed, use `git checkout-index` to extract files from the index into a separate area (a temporary work-tree, so that you don't clobber files in the regular work-tree).

Comment: But what I want to do is to auto-fix lint errors during pre-commit without affecting unstaged partials and files.

Comment: *Finding* them is reasonable, albeit a bit problematic ("warning: your staged version of foo probably has a bug on line 72 ... by the way that line appears nowhere in your current work-tree, and is not in your HEAD commit, it's only in the staged file"). *Fixing* them is more difficult: where will you *store* the fixed version? What if the automated fix is *wrong?*