# git push shows already up-to-date even if local changes are there

Tags: git, github

I got a problem when trying to push a new change from my local repository to GitHub. First, I did a 
`git commit -a`, and then `git push origin master`. Which gave me error:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:user/repo.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
```

So I figured there had been changes in the GitHub repo since my last pull and I then did `git pull origin master` which worked fine, but when I now do `git push origin master` I get:

```
From github.com:user/repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

But the the new file I added is not showing up on GitHub. It is still present in my local repo though. When I try type `git commit -a`, it says:

```
nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

and `git branch -v` gives:

```
* master 525fad2 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:user/repo
```

Answer (score 1):

It may have been stashed when you did your pull.

Try

```
git status
```

To see what is going on and look if its stashed

```
git stash show
```

If it is stashed you need to apply it

```
git stash apply
```

Use apply instead of pop as apply leaves the stash around for easy re-try of the apply, or for looking at, etc
If it is stashed then look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19003191/21063 for a more compreshesive explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This issue was resolved unexpectedly the next time I did `git push origin master` it worked..

Answer (score 1):

If you do a git status you should see something similar to this:

` On branch develop

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
   bb1.c
```

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
`

So you would need to do a git add bb1.c   to first add the file for tracking before doing your commit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This issue was resolved unexpectedly the next time I did `git push origin master` it worked..