# Using git, is there a way to reapply the changes but not commit the changes?

Tags: git

If I switch over to a new branch and commit the files (and push to GitHub as a backup), I found that once I switch back to the old branch, the files all became unmodified -- as if they were never modified since the last commit.

In this case, can I make the files modified like before?

I can

```
git rebase tmp-branch
```

and get those changes, but this action also apply the commit to my current branch. Is there a way to not make the commit happen, but just let the files be modified and remain uncommitted?

Comment: Is `stash`ing what you're looking for? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: can stash solve it?  Is it first by stashing, switch to new branch, apply stash, commit, and switch back to old branch, and apply stash again? But what if I didn't stash and I already committed in the other branch?

Comment: I'm fairly certain, yes.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Apparently the Git folks have thought of this already.
You can pass the `-n` flag to `cherry-pick` to apply the changes of another commit, and stop before creating a new one.

```
git checkout old-branch       # Go back to the old branch, files are unmodified

git cherry-pick -n tmp-branch # Apply the changes from tmp-branch's tip
```

Comment: oh boy... git is somewhat like tweaking your car at the low level... maybe that's why guys like it

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `stash` family of git commands

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

It allows you to store changes without committing them, switch to other branches, and the "pop" the stash when you return.

Here's some basic examples of it's use

http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/10/stashing-your-changes.html

From that page

*Add your changes to the index using*

```
git add .
```

*Or add individual files to the index, your pick. Stash your changes away with:*

```
git stash
```

*And boom! You’re back to your original working state. Got that bug fixed? Bring your work back with:*

```
git stash apply
```

*You can also do multiple layers of stashes, so make sure to use*

```
git stash list
```

*To check out all of your current ones. If you need to apply a stash from deeper in the stack, that’s easy too. Here’s how to apply the second stash you’ve got:*

```
git stash apply stash@{1}
```

*You can also easily apply the top stash on the stack by using:*

```
git stash pop
```

*A note with this command, it deletes that stash for good, while apply does not. You can manually delete stashes with:*

```
git stash drop <id>
```

*Or delete all of the stored stashes with:*

```
git stash clear
```

Comment: could you maybe list the steps for this particular situation? And what if I didn't do stash, then is it not possible to achieve what I want in the original question?

Comment: I'll try, I mostly use a GUI that supports this. If you didn't do stash, then I think you're changes were overwritten. In my GUI, it prevents you from doing that though so I'm not sure.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 nevermind, it seems you can recover unstashed changes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003009/git-how-to-recover-stashed-uncommitted-changes

Comment: isn't the link above about stashed changes that were later on unstashed?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 You're right, my mistake. I'm not entirely sure if you can recover unstashed changes after changing branches, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

**Git:** Stash unstaged changes

This will stash all modifications that you did not git add:

```
git stash -k
```

Note that newly created (and non-added) files will remain in your working directory unless you also use the -u switch.

```
git stash -k -u
```

Also, your working directory must be clean (i.e. all changes need to be added) when you git stash pop later on.