# After git stashing my project contents are not updated anymore how do I get back all my files

Tags: git, git-stash, gitkraken

Please, take it easy on me guys, I don't really understand stashing w/git, I only understand git add, status and basic stuff about git, Hope you'd be really understanding with me about this

I stashed all my project files since that current changes is not yet finished so I did git stash and when I moved to another branch by `git checkout ...`

I commited my updated changes to the master branch and pushed it to its github repo but when I run my updated project with its local server, I found out that I don't have my updated project files. like all my updated contents were now gone, how do I get back to those.

[image]

Comment: What `git stash` does is commit your files into a commit that is not on any branch, and then do a `git reset --hard` to reset your index/staging-area and work-tree. When you use `git push`, you generally use branch names to select commits to send to the other Git. Since stash commits are on *no* branch, this never sends the stash commits. You'll need to un-stash the stash, and make a more-normal commit, and push that.

Comment: Specifically all the files in : `git stash@{1}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-stash%5D+restore+files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover stashed uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003009/how-to-recover-stashed-uncommitted-changes)

Comment: yep, instead of commiting the files I did stash them so how Do I recover those ?

Comment: Hey do you know of any ideas wherein I can see a birds-eye view of the files inside the project old and new. like all the files history of commits and changes and stashes..

Answer (score 0):

You can get back your stash changes by writing "git stash pop" or if you want to keep changes in stash stack also then you can write "git stash apply".

Comment: On a specific stash how do I do it ? especially `stash@{1}`

Comment: try "git stash apply stash@\{1}"