# Git backup git stash

Tags: git, gitlab

I did git stash from the branch. How to get my files before git stash?

```
git stash
git checkout other-branch
git stash pop
```

I did not save them before.

Comment: Could you clarify? What do you get, what did you expect?

Comment: You generally _can't_ undo the changes made to your working directory by applying the stash.

Comment: Save *them*? Save what? Which files? `git stash` makes a stash copy, `git stash pop` applies the stash to your working folder, inbetween you checked out a branch, which files do you want brought back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover stashed uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003009/how-to-recover-stashed-uncommitted-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "I want my files as they were before I ran the initial `git stash`" : go back to the commit you were in before you called `git checkout other-branch`, and reapply the stash

```
# clean your worktree :
git stash

# go back to the previous branch :
git checkout the/active/branch/before/other-branch

# apply the stash :
git stash pop
```

You can use `git stash apply` instead of `git stash pop` if you want to "apply the stash" several times.

If you mean : "I want my files as they were before I ran `git stash pop`", just re-stash the content :

```
git stash
```